# Where does Nammalwar say that he was born right after Krishna departed the Earth?

Tags: krishna, history, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, alwar

The Alwars (also spelled Azhwars) are a group of 12 ancient Vaishnava saints who lived in Tamil Nadu and are famous for their poetry in praise of Vishnu. The collection of their 4000 poems, known as the Naalayira Divya Prabhandam, is considered by many to be the "Dravida Veda", or South Indian Veda. The Alwars are crucially important figures in the history of Vaishnavism; it is the beliefs and principles embodied in the Alwars' poems that ultimately gave rise to the Sri Vaishnava sect (of which I'm a member).

Most historians believe that the 12 Alwars from the 6th century AD to the 9th century AD.  But traditional Sri Vaishnava accounts assign them far older dates.  For instance, as I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6867/36) the first four Alwars are said to have been born in the Dwapara Yuga, all the way back in 4203 BC!  (That's a thousand years before the Pandavas were born.)

But my question is about another Alwar, Sadagopan aka Nammalwar, one of the most famous Alwars. (The Sadari in Sri Vaishnava temples represents Nammalwar, as I discuss [here](http://%20(The%20Sadari%20in%20Sri%20Vaishnava%20temples%20represents).) He is said to have been born in the beginning of the Kali Yuga, right after Krishna had departed the Earth.  [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=2e4ZAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22born%20six%20weeks%20late%22&pg=PA115#v=onepage&q&f=false) is what Alkoṇḍavilli Govindāchārya in his book "The Divine Wisdom of the Dravida Saints":

> St. Nammazhvar who was born just forty five days after the Ascension of Lord Krishna, groaned thus from love: "Sinful man that I am, I have been born six weeks late! Ah! that what had reathed the lip (i.e., Krishna) hath slipped away!!" ... ["Piranda" v-10]

My question is, where does Nammalwar say that he was born six weeks too late to see Krishna?  Govindacharya cites Nammalwar's poem "Pirandha", which is indeed poem V-10 of Nammalwar's Thiruvaimozhi.  But you can read [this translation](http://www.ibiblio.org/sripedia/ebooks/tvm/tvm5-x.html) and [this translation](http://thiruvaymozhi-5th-6thdecad.blogspot.ae/p/pirandhavarum.html) of the poem; I don't see anything resembling the quote above.

So did Govindacharya cite the wrong poem or what?  Does anyone know of some other poem of Nammalwar where he regrets being born slightly too late to see Krishna?