# Bhagwat Gita Original Version

Tags: scripture, history, bhagavad-gita

I want to purchase Bhagwat Gita in Hindi. Which is the original one? How can we verify if it's not duplicate? There are many in the market with the same name.

Comment: see this question for more info - http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10246/why-there-are-two-versions-of-chapter-1-verse-8-of-bhagavad-geetha/10258?noredirect=1#comment24518_10258