# Where in the Rig Veda are the 10 Upanishads?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, upanishads

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upanishads#Association_with_Vedas) it suggests there are **10** Upanishads embedded in the Rig Veda.

I have scoured Google but have not found anything saying something like "The 10 Upanishads of the Rig Veda are located in Hymns #X, #Y, and #Z". Where are they located in the [Rig Veda](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/index.htm)???

BTW, what do all these columns mean? How do I go about finding the Upanishads in the Rig Veda, or these other columns?

[image]

Comment: This classification is unnecessarily confusing, and the 10/11 principal Upanishads are not all in the rig veda. The problem with Wikipedia is that it uses Western scholars that are modern day orientalists as sources for Hinduism (they are neither sympathizers nor accurate). I would suggest you find Indian sources rather than them. Here are two Indian scholars -  https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey/mode/2up, and http://consciouslivingfoundation.org/ebooks/13/CLF-HistoryOfIndianPhilosophy.pdf

Comment: Does [this](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Upani%E1%B9%A3ad) help? Also, look at [this article](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/%E1%B9%9Agveda). Once you've figured out, maybe you can write your own answer. 

Comment: Related: [What are the Vedas technically?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18989/277)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a narrow/strict sense, Vedas means [Samhitas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samhita) only while in a broad sense (According to Mimansas), Vedas means Samhitas, Brahmanas, Aranyakas and Upanishads. As I've mentioned in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/39844/277), there are three distinct opinions among scholars whether Upanishads are part of Vedas or not.

All you want to know is about [Shakhas of Vedas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakha). As explained in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31727/277) Samhitas of Vedas are divided in Shakhas and rest of Vedas (Brahmanas, Aranyakas and Upanishads) are associated with Vedas through these Shakhas. Each Shalhsas is said to have their Brahmanas.

**Principal Upanishads can be found in Aranyakas or in Brahmanas not in Samhitas of Vedas** (except Isha Upanishad which is part of Yajurveda Samhita). You can read those 10 Upanishads associated with Rigveda on [Vedanta Shastras Library](https://www.shastras.com/upanishads/upanishads-rig-veda/). Where [you are searching](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/index.htm) is the Samhita of Rigveda in which Upanishads are **not located** as I have said Vedas usually means Samhitas of Vedas.

It may be worthy to mention that out of 10, Aitareya and Kaushitaki are principal Upanishads.