# What are some of the devotional works by Madhusudan Saraswati?

Tags: krishna, bhakti, resource

[Madhusudhan Saraswati](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhus%C5%ABdana_Sarasvat%C4%AB), the author of the famous work, [Advaitasiddhi](http://www.advaitasiddhi.org/) was a Vaishnava belonging to the Shankarite sect. A great devotee of Shri Krishna, he is said to have been initially against Advaita but later accepted it to be the highest truth.

I want to know whether he has written any devotional works dedicated to Shree Krishna? If yes, what are the names of these works? Are any of these works available online in English?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notable devotional works of Madhusudana Saraswati are:

- AnandamandAkinI (आनन्दमन्दाकिनी)
- Bhagavad Bhakti Rasayanam (भगवद्भक्तिरसायनम्)
- Ishvarapratipattiprakasha (ईश्वरप्रतिपत्तिप्रकाशः)

All are available to read in Sanskrit at [Sanskritdocuments.org](https://sanskritdocuments.org/sanskrit/madhusudanasarasvati/). Upon searching I found that Hindi translation of Bhagvad Bhakti Rasayana is available on [Internet Archive](https://archive.org) but I didn't find English translation. (Will update the answer when I find)

Useful information from [Preceptors of Advaita](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/Preceptors%20of%20Advaita%20-%2041.html)  lists his works:

> Madhusudana wrote a number of works on bhaktimarga and also on the Advaita Vedanta as propounded by Sankara.  His works are Anandamandakini, Bhaktirasayana, Isvarapratipattiprakasa, Mahimnastotra-vyakhya, Harilila-vyakhya, Bhagavataprathamaslokatika, Vedantakalpalatika, Siddhantabindu, Samkshepasariraka-vyakhya, Gudarthadipika, Advaita-siddhi and Advaita-ratna-rakshana.

And couple of them are purely devotional:

> - **Anandamandakini** is an original poem of more than one hundred slokas in praise of Lord Krishna.  This work was his maiden attempt.  One can easily appreciate the fervent devotion of the author to Sri Krishna.
> - **Bhaktirasayana** is a great treatise on bhakti.

Comment: Btw, Prasthana Bheda is also one useful work of Madhusudana Saraswati I quoted [in this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16226/277)