# Does smriti allows king to make new constitution?

Tags: scripture, puranas, smriti, epics

Do smriti allows to make constitution ?
My point is smriti is supreme constitution.under smriti can king can make new rules and new punishment .
Do smriti/vedic/puranic scriptures given freedom to make new rules and new punishment under smriti .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Hinduism entertain new Smritis?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11450/does-hinduism-entertain-new-smritis)

Comment: Smriti literally mean remembered. So they only apply fully to their time and place. Thus the king can make his own rules, using the smriti as inspiration, ignoring things he doesn't think applies now.

Comment: -@Archit I am not talking about new smtiti . I am talking about do king as freedom to make new rules.

Comment: @Aupakarana Abhibhaa ji my question is according to smriti and vedic and Hindu scriptures. Hindu can follow constitution and Hindu notion can have constitution

Comment: For example : Nepal is Hindu nation, telangana is Hindu nation . do Hindu scriptures are allow to make constitution to two Hindu nations

Comment: Well, since smriti aren't exact instructions, yes, the nation should be able to have a constitution more suited to their current needs.

Comment: To smriti tells that

Comment: Which smriti tells that can I have reference