# Are there Hindu texts which do not fall under the Sruti-Smriti classification?

Tags: smriti, sruti, classification

This talks about what is the difference between Sruti and Smriti: [What is difference between Shruti and Smriti?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8591/what-is-difference-between-shruti-and-smriti)

The above link also talks about what can be classified as Sruti i.e. Vedas and some related texts.

Do all other texts come under Smriti? Or, only some other texts can be classified under Smriti and the rest do not fall under this classification?

Answer (score 4):

Hindu scriptures can be broadly classified as follows:

> 1.[Vedas](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Veda)
>
> 2.[Upanishads](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Upanishad)
>
> 3.[Smritis](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Smriti)
>
> 4.[Agama & Tantra](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Agama)
>
> 5.[Darsana](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Darsana)
>
> 6.[Itihasa](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Itihasa)

Of these 6 divisions everything except the 6th one ,viz:Itihasa, come under either Sruti or Smriti classifications.

Itihasa comprises of  the Ramayana & the Mahabharata.

Comment: The link mentioned in the question contradicts what you are saying regarding Itihasa. (Sorry, I mentioned the wrong link before)

Comment: Well, that answer does not even mention any sources whereas i have given one of the most trustworthy sources for hinduism related stuffs in my answer.

Comment: Okay, that's a valid point.

Comment: Is this an exhaustive list? e.g. How would you classify texts like: 
Rasaratna Samuchaya - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasaratna_Samuchaya
Rasa Ratnakara - 
http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/rasa-ratnakara-NZA341/

Comment: Your listings and comments are not exactly correct. First, the Upanishads are part of the Vedas, they are not separate from it. Second, what is called Darsana is really commentators...not really scripture per se.  Third, the Puranas should be listed separately. Fourth, all the divisions do not fall under the classification of Smriti. Smriti are the laws formulated by Manu, Yajnavalka, and others. The Agamas, Tantra,  do not fall under Smriti.

Comment: I know that Agamas ,tantra do not fall under smriti.Thats why they are listed separate ly.My listing and classification is not incorrect.There can be very many classifications and the one that i gave is one of them.Even the site from which i quoted knows that upanishads are essentially sruti but there are good reasons to mention it separately.