# Can Shudras listen to/chant the Hanuman Chalisa?

Tags: shudra, hanuman-chalisa

Can Shudras read/chant/listen to the Hanuman Chalisa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16627), Shudras are not supposed to undergo Vedadhyayana, but are allowed to read the Puranas and other religious texts. It is simply because Upanayanam has not been performed for them, which is important for the vibrations that emanate from chanting mantras.

Therefore, any texts non- vedic in nature can be read by them.

Evidence from verse 38-39 of the Hanuman Chalisa itself:

> **जो** सत बार पाठ कर **कोई**। छूटहि बंदि महा सुख होई॥३८॥
> जो यह पढै़ हनुमान चलीसा। होय सिद्धि साखी गौरीसा॥३९॥
>
> **Whosoever** (जो कोई भी पढ़े) reads this a hundred times, his bonds are tattered and bliss befalls him. Who reads the Hanuman attains to Siddhi, a witness is Shri Gauripati Shiva Mahadeva himself.

Thus we can see that **Hanuman chalisa can be read by all**. There is no prohibition like vedic mantras.