# What is the difference among Shruti, Smriti and Purana traditions?

Tags: puranas, tradition, smriti, sruti

What are the differences among the traditions of Shruti, Smriti and Purana traditions as in Shrauta Parampara, Smarta Parampara and Pauranika Parampara?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Veda, Purana, upanishad, Smritis, Granth?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21609/5212). I am editing out the difference between scriptures as that part is already asked and answer. So please limit the question to traditions. Otherwise, it will be too broad and also duplicate.