# What are 'Adi Granth' in Hinduism ? Is it a properly-defined technical term?

Tags: vedas

I've heard people refer to Vedas as `Adi Granth`.

1. Is `Adi Granth` used as a special term, and if yes, which books does it refer to ?
2. Do the Vedas or other scriptures themselves use this term ? If yes, where ?

Comment: Where you came across Vedas being referred to as Adi granth? I have only seen Sikh scripture being referred to as Adi granth, never Vedas.

Comment: @Aks I think OP meant primary scripture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the primary authentic sources of Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/631/what-are-the-primary-authentic-sources-of-hinduism)

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring as canonical text, then it depends upon hinduism sects.

Almost all sects assign Vedas as canonical text authority. 
But In various hindu sects they may assign "additional texts (like gita, ramayana, some purana) " also on the canonical text level authority.

==========

Also taken literally, Adi granth term has not been used in hindu scriptures. But if we interpret it as "Adi granth" meaning 'the text which was in the beginning', then also vedas only - fit on that term, as per belief.