# Did Sukracharya invite Lord Srinivasa for marriage with Goddess Padmavathi?

Tags: vishnu, venkateshwara, shukracharya

When I went to Tirupati a week ago, I read the story of Venkateswara on the walls of the main temple. It says Sukracharya invited Lord Srinivasa for marriage with Padmavathi on behalf of Gods. I could not take photo of this as I was inside the main temple.

How could Sukracharya invite Srinivasa for marriage on behalf of Gods, when he (Sukracharya) clearly hates Lord Vishnu as Lord Vishnu killed his mother? Did he really invite Srinivasa?

Comment: I checked both the Tirumala Sthala Purana (from my question [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/753/36)) and the Venkatachala Mahatmya of the Skanda Purana, and neither one mentions anything about Sukracharya being involved at the wedding.  Is it possible that you misread Shuka as Shukra?  Because Shuka was involved in inviting Venkateshwara.  By the way, where in the temple is the story written?

Comment: By the way, there are some indications of Sukracharya helping the gods; see my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3527/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan On the walls opposite to Vimana Venkateswara. But i read it twice. Does the name of Suka involves first "sa" or second "Sa"? Does Sukra hate Vishnu?

Comment: I don't know Sanskrit, so this is imprecise, but Shuka is spelled with sha as in ship, not sa as in Sam.  In any case, it's possible that TTD made a typo in what they wrote.

Comment: And yeah, I'd assume Sukracharya would some animus towards Vishnu for killing his mother, but I'm not sure if any scriptures mention him having negative feelings towards him.  The only person that Sukracharya is mentioned as having hatred towards is Brihaspato, because Sukracharya and Brihaspati were both students of Brihaspati's father Angiras but Sukracharya left Angiras' ashram because he thought Angiras was showing favoritism to Brihaspati.  That rivalry ultimately led to the Tarakamaya war, which I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3106/36

Comment: Telugu  has three "sa". sa, Sa and Sha. Sa is same as "Sa" in Siva not "Sha". It's equivalent to "la" in Tamizh. Ok. I might have misread క (ka) as క్ర (kra) or it might be typo mistake of TTD