# What scripture says devotees of other gods eventually become devotees of Vishnu in future births?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, shaivism, vedanta-desika

The Rahasyatraya Sara is a work by the Sri Vaishnava Acharya Vedanta Desikan, concerning the meaning of the [Rahasya Traya](http://www.srivaishnavan.com/faqs/ans_secrets.php) or three secrets of the Sri Vaishnava sect (of which I'm a member). In [this excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6akt.jpg) from the Rahasyatraya Sara, Vedanta Desikan discusses why Hindu scripture describes other gods as aids to attaining Moksha, when Vishnu is described as the sole path to Moksha:

> If, in some places, these gods are spoken of as assisting in the attainment of moksha, it should be understood to mean that they, like Acharyas, assist by imparting knowledge and in other such ways.  This is also the purport of the following passage; **"The man who is a devotee of the god of the sun (Surya) will, after seven more births, become a devotee of Rudra by the Sun's grace.  He who is a devotee of Sankara will, after seven more births, become a devotee of Vishnu by the grace of Sankara." And again:- "He who is a devotee of Vasudeva will, after those seven births, become one with Vasudeva by His grace."**

My question is, what scripture contains these quotes about a Saura (devotee of Surya) becoming a Shaivite after seven births, a Shaivite becoming a Vaishnava after seven more births, and a Vaishnava attaining Moksha after yet another seven births?

I expect it's from one of the Puranas, but I'm not sure which one.  Are there any commentaries on Vedanta Desikan's work which address this?

Comment: Even if the quote regarding Vasudeva (Krishna) is true, then it will apply only for the last ~5000 years. Hence such scripture might have originated within last 5k years. Such a scripture is not universal or timeless. Also, the magic figure of 7 births seems to be problematic, because if due to continuous efforts a Jeeva become selfless, then he may attain the Moksha immediately irrespective of its then current situation.

Comment: @iammilind First of all, Vaasudeva has always been a name of Vishnu, long before the birth of Krishna; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6923/36 Vishnu has been called Vaasudeva in numerous scriptures including the Valmiki Ramayana, the Taittiriya Aranyaka of the Yajur Veda, and the Pancharatra Agamas.  In fact, the whole reason that Krishna was born to someone with the name Vasudeva is so that his name would be Vaasudeva, reflecting the name of Vishnu.

Comment: @iammilind Also, just because a scripture originated in the past 5000 years does not mean that its truth isn't timeless and universal.  The Mahahbharata, the Puranas, and the Brahma Sutras were all composed by Vyasa in the end of the Dwapara Yuga/beginning of the Kali Yuga.  But their truths are still timeless and universal, because Vyasa composed these works using his abilities as a Trikalajnani.  So if the quotes in my question are found in one of those works, it will be true, full stop, not merely true for the past 5000 years.

Comment: @iammilind In any case, I don't think the quote is precluding the attainment of Moksha in other ways.  It's just saying that if you're living an otherwise ordinary life with the one distinguishing feature being that you're a devotee of Surya, then seven births later you'll become a devotee of Shiva, seven births later you'll become a devotee of Vishnu, and seven births after that Vishnu will grant you Moksha out of compassion.  That doesn't stop you from doing other things to get Moksha in the mean time.

Comment: Sorry if I misread your post. If *Vaasudeva = Vishnu* (and not necessarily *Krishna*) in this context, then my words are wrong. My logic was based on exclusivity of Krishna as god rather than Vishnu. It was not against 5000 years. Even something truthful told today also can be timeless + universal. Transferring a devotee from Shiva to Vishnu is something debatable. Looking forward for an answer which would also contain a proper definition of *Vishnu* which is neither limited to current Indian subcontinent nor limited only to how Indians define *Vishnu*.

Comment: @iammilind "Looking forward for an answer which would also contain a proper definition of Vishnu which is neither limited to current Indian subcontinent nor limited only to how Indians define Vishnu."  I'm not sure what you mean.  How Indians define Vishnu is the correct way to define Vishnu, insofar as those Indians are relying on Hindu scripture for their understanding of Vishnu.  I'm not sure what the point is of a definition of Vishnu that's from something other than Hindu scripture.  But you may be interested in my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6896/36

Comment: @iammilind "Transferring a devotee from Shiva to Vishnu is something debatable."  Well, it's debatable for the time being, at least until we find a scriptural reference to confirm it.  That's why I asked the question.

Comment: I think you can find this quote from any of the "sattvic" puranas.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, if you find it in one of them, please tell me.

Comment: since no citation has come up in 2 years, perhaps it doesn't exist.

Comment: @SK Lots of my questions are unanswered for 2 years or longer.  Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.  All it indicates is that we need more knowledgeable users to join the site.  My answer could probably be answered in two minutes if someone looked in the subcommentaries on the Rahasyatraya Sara.

Comment: @keshav srinivasan - so I suppose this sectarian assertion will stand without citations indefinitely.

Comment: @SK Well, it's a question, not an assertion.  And hopefully the site can attract more experts to answer such questions.

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan"My question is, what scripture contains these quotes" has an implicit assertion that SOME scripture does contain these quotes.

Comment: Well, Vedanta Desikan is claiming that it's a scriptural quote, so I want to know which scripture it's from.

Comment: do sectarian vaishnavite works qualify as scripture?  if so, vedanta desikan saying it makes it scripture;.

Comment: @SK Well, there are varying levels of authority in regard to Sabda Pramana says.  The Rahasyatraya Sara is not as authoritative as the scriptures it quotes.

Answer (score 1):

#### This is stated in the Brahma Mahā-Purāṇa.

Although the "seven-births" parts are not explicitly stated (and the devotee ladder starts from Agni-deva), the rest of it, all matches with what Vedanta Desikan says in his work.

> [Chapter 121](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-purana-english/d/doc216278.html) - Manifestation of Māyā, Brahma-purāṇa
>
> [व्यासमुनिसंवादे विष्णुभक्तिहेतुकथनम्](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A8%E0%A5%A8%E0%A5%AF)
>
> व्यास उवाच
>
> > Vyāsa said:
>
> श्रृणुध्वं मुनिशार्दूलाः प्रवक्ष्याम्यनुपूर्वशः । यथा कृष्णे
> भवेद्‌भक्तिः पुरुषस्य महाफला ॥ २२९.३ ॥
>
> > 3. Listen, O leading sages. I shall mention in due order how a person shall attain devotion to Viṣṇu with great benefit.
>
> ---
>
> संसारेऽस्मिन्महाघोरे सर्वभूतभयावहे । महामोहकरे नॄणां नानादुः खशताकुले
> ॥ २२९.४ ॥
>  तिर्यग्योनिसहस्रेषु जायमानः पुनः पुनः । कथंचिल्लभते जन्म
> देही मानुष्यकं द्विजाः ॥ २२९.५ ॥
>
> > - 4 & 5. The worldly existence is extremely terrible. It strikes terror into all living beings. It causes sorrow to men. Hundreds of
> >   miseries abound in it. A soul is born again and again in thousands of
> >   species of lower living organisms, O brahmins, and with great
> >   difficulty it attains human birth.
>
> ---
>
> मानुषत्वेऽपि विप्रत्वं विप्रत्वेऽपि विवेकिता । विवेकाद्धर्मबुद्धिस्तु
> बुद्ध्या तु श्रेयसां ग्रहः ॥ २२९.६ ॥
>
> > 6. After human birth, he attains brahmin-hood, power of discrimination, a sense of piety, and happiness in successive births.
>
> ---
>
> यावत्पापक्षयं पुंसां न भवेज्जन्मसंचितम् । तावन्न जायते भक्तिर्वासुदेवे
> जगन्मये ॥ २२९.७ ॥
>
> > 7. **Until the ultimate destruction of all sins of men accumulated in different births, devotion to Vāsudeva (Vishnu) who is identical with the universe, is
> >    not possible.**
>
> ---
>
> तस्माद्वक्ष्यामि भो विप्रा भक्तिः कृष्णे यथा भवेत् । अन्यदेवेषु या
> भक्तिः पुरुषस्येह जायते ॥ २२९.८ ॥
>  कर्मणा मनसा वाचा तद्‌गतेनान्तरात्मना
> । तेन तस्य भवेद्‌भक्तिर्यजने मुनिसत्तमाः ॥ २२९.९ ॥
>
> > - 8 & 9. **Hence, O brahmins, I shall tell you how devotion to Viṣṇu is effected. A person may be devoted to other Devas mentally, verbally
> >   and physically. His soul is directed to those gods. Thereby, O
> >   excellent sages, he may become inclined to perform sacrifices.**
>
> ---
>
> स करोति ततो विप्रा भक्तिं चाग्नेः समाहितः । तुष्टे हुताशने तस्य
> भक्तिर्भवति भास्करे ॥ २२९.१० ॥
>
> > 10. **Then, O brahmins, with great concentration and purity of mind be begins to love the Fire-god (Agni-deva). When the fire-god is propitiated he
> >     becomes a devotee of the Sun-god (Surya-deva).**
>
> ---
>
> पूजां करोति सततमादित्यस्य ततो द्विजाः । प्रसन्ने भास्करे तस्य
> भक्तिर्भवति शंकरे ॥ २२९.११ ॥
>
> > 11. **O brahmins, he worships the Sun-god (Surya-deva) regularly. When that god is pleased he becomes devoted to Śaṅkara (Shiva).**
>
> ---
>
> पूजां करोति विधिवत्स तु शंभोः प्रयत्नतः । तुष्टे त्रिलोचने तस्य
> भक्तिर्भवति केशवे ॥ २२९.१२ ॥
>
> > 12. **He performs the worship of Śambhu (Shiva) duly and strenuously. When the three-eyed god is satisfied he becomes devoted to Keśava (Vishnu).**
>
> ---
>
> संपूज्य तं जगन्नाथं वासुदेवाख्यमव्ययम् । ततो भुक्तिं च मुक्तिं च स
> प्राप्नोति द्विजोत्तमाः ॥ २२९.१३ ॥
>
> > 13. **By worshipping the imperishable lord of the universe named Vāsudeva (Vishnu), O excellent brahmins, he attains worldly pleasures and
> >     salvation.**
>
> English Translation by G. P. Bhatt

One may access the Gita Press Gorakhpur's abridged Hindi version of the above [from here](https://archive.org/details/brahma-puran-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n405/mode/2up). Also, the alternate link for the English Translation [from here](https://archive.org/details/brahma_purana_english_full/page/n673/mode/2up).

- On a side note, a similar thematic narration, yet again from the Vaishnavite perspective, is also found in the Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa Verses [2.7.19.(13-26)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371721.html#note-t-139612).

---

Further, similar "hierarchies" may exist for other sects' Supreme deities too; two examples out of many, being as follows -

- One instance of which is described in the Devī Bhāgavata-purāṇa [Chapter 1, Book 5](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57190.html); establishing the hierarchy of - 
   [ Brahmā < Vishnu < Rudra < Devi ] in that order.

- Yet another similar hierarchy is found in the [Kulārṇava Tantra (II. 7-8)](https://archive.org/details/Kularnava/page/n27/mode/2up?view=theater) too, which establishes the hierarchy as follows -
  Vedācāra < Vaiṣṇavācāra < Śaivācāra < Dakṣinācāra < Vāmācāra < Siddhāntācāra < Kaulācāra