# Do any of Vaikhanasa text associate itself with Vedanta philosophy?

Tags: agamas, vishishtadvaita, vaikhanasa, grihya-sutra

As I had posted a question on popular philosophies of Hinduism. In one of the [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19169/which-philosophy-is-the-most-popular-in-hinduism) it is mentioned that Vaikhanasa is associated to Vishishthadvaita vedanta.

**But when Vaikhanasa itself is called as "agama" how it can be associated with Vedanta which comes under nigama?**

**Among the Vaikhanasa sutras (grihya, shrauta etc) and related Samhita texts, are there any which acknowledge its association with the Vedanta?**

Though there could be a commentary on Vedanta sutra by a vaikhanasa [priest](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10187/is-the-vaikhanasa-commentary-on-the-brahma-sutras-available-in-english). But I want to know the references directly from their core texts. Because the followers may write commentaries on many subjects which may not be necessarily related to the actual ideology.

Comment: Ramanujacharya unified Pancharatra Agamas with Vedanta (Upanishads) through his VisistaAdvaita Philosophy. Though Adi Shankara rejected them, Ramanujacharya's goal was to unify both Agamas and Upanishads and he did that through VA philosophy.So, VA gives importance to Agama and Vedanta.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Pancharatra or vaikhanasa as such is not related to vedanta. But ramanuja followers follow vedanta. it is not mandatory to follow vedanta for those who practicing pancharatra or vaikhanasa.

Comment: The Vaikhanasa Agamas along with the Vaikhanasa Shrauta Sutras, Grihya Sutras, and Dharma Sutras all came from the sage Vikhanasa, who lived long before the composition of the Brahma Sutras, so they obviously don't mention the Vedanta school.  Still, all Vaikhanasa Acharyas believe in Srinivasa Dikshitar's Lakshmi-Visistadvaita Bhashya, the Vaikhanasa commentary on the Brahma Sutras.

Comment: It's similar to how Sri Vaishnavas follow the Pancharatra Agamas, and the Pancharatra Agamas don't mention the Vedanta school (again due to age difference), but it is still the case that all Sri Vaishnava Acharyas believe in Ramanujacharya's Sri Bhashya, the Sri Vaishnava commentary on the Brahma Sutras.

Comment: If they dont mention brahma sutra then fine but what about upanishads ? that should be mentioned to correlate