# What Vedanta philosophy is followed by Varkari Vaishnavas?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, vaishnavism, sects

Which Vedanta philosophy is followed by people belonging to the Varkari sect?

Comment: If.it was vedanta then why would.it be called varkari at all ? Its not necessary for all paths to follow vedanta. Please understand that..

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I didn't understand your point.

Comment: Why are you linking every sect with vedanta ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Just wanted to know what Vedanta philosophy is followed by sects.

Comment: Ok but there are many sects which dont follow any vedanta.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi How is that possible? I mean Vedanta is essential right?

Comment: Not at all essential. I myself am against vedanta. There are people who just follow vedas and not vedanta. Just follow agama and not vedanta. You have to see with a broad mind.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi You reject Vedanta?

Comment: haven't you seen my threads and posts and chat ? :)

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Um...no

Comment: I think theirs is bhakti yoga. Vedanta is for gnyana yogis.

Comment: @moonstar One can follow Bhakti Yoga and still subscribe to the Vedanta school.  Sri Vaishnavas believe in Visistadvaita, Madhvas believe in Dvaitadvaita, Gaudiya Vaishnavas believe in Achintya Bhedabheda, Pushtimargiss believe in Shuddhadvaita, etc.  So similarly the Varkari sect may subscribe to some Vedantic philosophy.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Rakesh Joshi is right, there are a few  Hindu sects that reject the Vedanta school; see my answer here for a list: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19170/36 In any case, I think the Varkari sect almost certainly subscribes to the Vedanta school.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Its seems mainly the Shaivite sects reject Vedanta.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Yes, there's a reason for that: the Vedanta school believes that Brahman is both the efficient cause and the material cause of the Universe.  The Shaiva Agamas disagree with that belief, instead saying that Brahman is only the efficient cause of the Universe (and the Brahma Sutras criticize them for that reason).  Whereas the Pancharatra Agamas agree with the Vedanta school on that.  So the difference in doctrine in different kinds of Agamas leads to a difference in what sects accept the Vedanta school and what sects rejects the Vedanta school.

Comment: @keshavsrinivasan I am not saying they are mutually exclusive. In fact one leads to the other quite often and in each's culmination, they exist together. Varkaris AFAIK are working class people dedicated to Vithal. Their form of worship is heavily skewed to bhakti I believe.

Comment: Suryakanta - @tezz provided info on various philosophies if shaiva sects. Check.

Comment: @keshavsrinivasan suryakanta uses the word Vedanta to mean philosophy. You are using it to mean uttaramimamsa. There is a gap

Comment: Wikipedia lists it under [Vaishnavism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaishnavism#Varkari-tradition_and_Vithoba-worship).
Though the different saints are seen to be from different traditions, they mostly followed some form of Advaita Vedanta with special role to Hari-bhakti. Though ISKCON forwards Tukaram as a Dvaitin, there is a mix of both Advaita and Dvaita in his works, and it is believed that he settled on Advaita later. (Posting this as a comment as short on time to provide sources)