# Are there any authenticated records of Ramanand Swami's (Kabir's guru) teachings?

Tags: vaishnavism, guru, ramanandi

I recently learned that Ramananda Swami was a guru of Kabir's and I am curious to learn more about his teachings. However have not been able to locate anything online as most of the current Google hits are all about the contemporary Ramananda Swami. Am keen to learn more about his work with the Vaishnava sampradaya.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short biography of Swami Ramananda's life, in poetic form, can be found in the [**Sri Bhaktamala**](https://archive.org/download/HindiBook-shriBhaktmalByShriNabhaJi/HindiBook-shriBhaktmalByShriNabhaJi.pdf).

In addition to many devotional poems, Swami Ramananda is credited to have authored two philosophical works, in Sanskrit, which lays the foundations of the Ramanandi school of Vaishnavism. These works are as follows:

1) Ramarchana Paddhati (You can read it, in Hindi [**here**](https://archive.org/download/RamarchanPaddhati/Ramarchan%20Paddhati.pdf).)

2) Vaishnava Mata Bhajabhaskara (You can read it, in a set of five volumes with a Sanskrit and Hindi commentary, by His Holiness Jagadguru Ramanandacharya Swami Sri Rameshwaranandacharya Ji Maharaj, [**here**](https://archive.org/details/vaishnavamatabjabhaskara/page/n9).)

Unfortunately, none of his works have been translated in English so far.

Also, many Ramanandi saints over the last century have come forth, claiming to have possessed Swami Ramananda's supposed third work, a commentary on the Brahma Sutras. However, in each and every case, these works seem to be of dubious origin, as seen in this [**question**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10180/have-any-ramanandi-commentaries-on-the-brahma-sutras-been-translated-into-englis).