# Which Mahavishnu/Vishnu got tired during material creation?

Tags: puranas, upapuranas

The significance of the Puranas and Upapuranas and their stories is known to any Indian worldwide.

The eternal story in which Mahavishnu (one of the three Parmatama expansions) gets extremely tired while material creation. And thus He gave us Amla, (gooseberry) which is a medicine for jiva's  overexertion, is also very important in Indian ancient cultural practices nationwide.

Question: which Mahavishnu does this, Kaaranodsayi Mahavishnu or Garbhodsayi Mahavishnu??

Comment: @Wikash_ https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/is-there-any-scripture-that-tells-story-about-lord-vishnu-and-mahavishnu

Comment: In the Vishnu purana there are 2 Vishnu's described and their names are not explicitly mentioned hence most hindus reject the Gaudiya Vaishnava theory about them.

Comment: @Wikash_ ask them do they also reject srimad Bhagvatam Mahapurana?? In the Bhagvatam there is a complete explaination of all the three parmatama expansions of Narayan;

Comment: this eternal story is also there in the Mahabharata, the Ekadashi fortnightly fasting story(Amliki ekadashi katha) and other shastric citations.

Comment: You do not understand. In puranic references and the mahabarata if one refers to Mahavishnu they just mean the "regular" Vishnu. This is a mistake a lot of Vaishnavas make.

Comment: How many Vishnus you know?

Comment: Just one and not three of the Gaudiya Vaishnavas.

Comment: @Wikash_ Ask jagat guru kripalu parisat..!! We are in constant touch with them for the authentic video files. till then rest in peace.

Comment: You know some gurus are just wrong. Do not blindly believe everything rather look where the evidence leads you.

Comment: @Wikash_ Ok. how can you tell evidences are authentic. Let us keep the gurus and the ghantals apart from it.

Comment: One method is to use a reliable process like the scientic method.

Comment: @Wikash_ what about four errors involved in material sense based observation and its scientific theories!!

Comment: There are no errors if you perform your experiment well.

Comment: lol. study vedic sutras related to these four error of material senses of observation; bhrama, pramada, vipralipsa, karnapatava.

Comment: @Wikash_ vedic sutras are always correct. interpretation is what needs to be correct.

Comment: @Wikash_ What do you mean regarding correctness of Shastras? Shastras are correct but unable to prove or Suras are wrong.

Comment: @Wikash_ "What do you mean regarding correctness of Shastras? Shastras are correct but unable to prove or Suras are wrong." we append, Shastra are always accurate, but usually misinterpreted as per the level of understanding of the person with impaired material senses of perception.

Comment: @user30612 Shastra's have never been proven to be accurate.

Comment: @Wikash_ then what is accurate? maintain integrity when  commenting!