# Why Hindu gods are always depicted with multiple hands and heads but not legs?

Tags: vedas, gods, idols

I have always wondered if there is any god with multiple legs ?  It may seem silly but I don't quite understand the need of multiple hands ( considering them as supreme being why do they need it ?). No gods in other religion have multiple hands and heads, only demons do.

Are there any description about multiple hands and heads in any holy scriptures ?

Comment: "Is there a god with multiple legs". Think that by the Vishnu Sahasranamam, Lord VIshnu is described as 'Sahasraaksha Sahasrapath' - 'Thousand eyes and thousand legs'. As far as "I don't quite understand the need of multiple hands" For that matter God neither need multiple hands nor any hands. In reality (advaita) God is formless and nameless. The different forms of God are His manifestations as per the devotion of the devotee. All the best

Comment: So, Hindu religion says that God is formless ? If there is no form then Brahma, Vishnu and Mahesh are also formless ?

Comment: According to Advaita (this is one branch in Hinduism, each branch such as Advaita, Vishistadvaita, Dvaita have their own beliefs), God or Brahman is in reality formless, nameless and absolute consciousness. As per the devotion of the devotee He takes up different forms such as Brahma, Vishnu and Mahesh. The trimurthi are in reality one and the same God (formless) but they have taken a form for the sake of the devotee. As said, this is the Advaita view, different branches within Hinduism believe in different things. All the best.

Comment: Here is some more information about the Trimurthi being one God: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahman. It gives the various views on God Brahman, according to various branches of Hindu philosophy. All the best. Good q buddy

Comment: @Sai The "Sahasraksha Sahasrapat" line is originally from the Purusha Sukta of the Rig Veda, and it describes Vishnu's Vishwarupam, aka his Aniruddha form, as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7661/36

Comment: @Utkarsh Brahman has both an aspect with a form and a formless aspect; see my answer here for how these aspects are understood in Vaishnavism: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6923/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yeah I just remembered that it is present in Purusha Sukta once you mentioned it. Thanks!

Comment: for Are there any description about multiple hands and heads in any holy scriptures ?, this might help http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6672/why-does-vishnu-have-eight-arms-when-krishna-and-arjuna-go-to-see-him

Comment: It is not practically possible to sculpt an idol or draw an image with many legs !

Answer (score 4):

**Kubera** (or Kuvera), the God of the riches, has [three legs](https://images.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Ftamilandvedas.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F10%2Fadilabad-dt-three-legs.jpg%3Fw%3D600&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.speakingtree.in%2Fblog%2F17-names-of-kubera-in-amarakosa&docid=m6r07WWBWwRQwM&tbnid=t7tFePKk3BfdcM%3A&vet=1&w=299&h=430&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim) and eight teeth.

As already descirbed in Monier-Williams Sanskrit-English Dictionary, 1899:

**kubera**  m. or in later Sanskṛt kuvera (originally) N. of a chief of the evil beings or spirits or darkness having the N. Vaiśravaṇa, AV. viii, 10, 28 ; ŚBr.  &c.;
(afterwards) the god of riches and treasure Mn. MBh.
  *he is represented as having three legs and only eight teeth*;

Answer (score 2):

There is famous Vishnu stuti **Purush suktam** in it there is first slock.
Here are two link in [HINDI](https://hindi.speakingtree.in/blog/content-363726) and [ENGLISH](https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/purushasuktam):

> सहस्त्रशीर्षा पुरुष:सहस्राक्ष:**सहस्रपात्** |
>
> स भूमि सर्वत: स्पृत्वाSत्यतिष्ठद्द्शाङ्गुलम् ||१||
>
> The Perfect Being has thousand (unlimited) heads, thousand (unlimited) eyes, **and thousand (unlimited) feet**. Having pervaded the whole earth (manifest universe), he remains ten fingers surplus (i.e. He is limitless). (1)
>
> जो सहस्रों सिरवाले, सहस्रों नेत्रवाले और **सहस्रों चरणवाले** विराट पुरुष हैं, वे सारे ब्रह्मांड को आवृत करके भी दस अंगुल शेष रहते हैं ||१||

I must say that it is created by **Brahma** and there for Vishnu loves it very much.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE! Please try to provide relevant info, the links might go dead in future and then answer would be of no use...

Answer (score 1):

I have a picture of **Mahakali , which has multiple heads, multiple hands and multiple legs** .
Hinduism believes that the Gods you worship ,are images which help you to progress Materially and Spiritually .So there is no restriction on the images you worship or the Mantras you recite.
 This is given in **" Yoga Darshana" by Patanjali**. I will give the exact "Shlokas" at a later time.
 Life Stories  of **Ramakrishna and Shiridi Sai Baba** , are examples of a saint **worshipping many forms of Gods** , which may include images from other religions.
 The image of "Chhinnamasta" is another example of an image that does not make sense.It is believed that worship of **Chhinnamasta** removes **suicidal thoughts**.

Comment: With all due respect, I am not interested in the pictures you have? are there any description in religious scriptures?

Comment: **Image of Chinnamasta makes no sense**, sir probably you need to learn more about Shaktism.

Comment: The image of Chinnmastika makes lots of sense, it is quite important and also wonderful symbolism in Shakta faith (she is one of my all time favorites Goddess ! ) 

Answer (score 0):

one symbolic reason for multiple hands and two feet only:

hands are meant to extend support...it could be for  blessing or healing or consecration; though there is specific function defined for each hand, hands reach out to devotees for any specific reason
in the case of feet, they are not meant for locomotion in case of Gods....they are meant for the followers to take refuge after doing which the hands scramble and get into action...

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE! You should cite sources.

Answer (score 0):

There are deities with more than 2 legs.

**Agni**

> The image of Agni in temples, represents him as an old man with red
>   body. He has two heads, a big belly and six eyes, seven arms in which
>   he holds objects like the spoon, ladle, fan etc., seven tongues, four
>   horns and **three legs**.

Hindu Gods and Goddesses, The Vedic Gods by Swami Harshananda

**Yajna**

> Visnu has been identified with Yajna or sacrifice in early Vedic
>   literature. ................ His image has two heads, seven hands,
>   **three legs** and four horns.

Hindu Gods and Goddesses, The Trinity *Vishnu* by Swami Harshananda

**Mahakali**

> .. Mahakali has ten faces and **ten feet**.

Hindu Gods and Goddesses, Sakti or the divine power as the Goddess *Durga* by Swami Harshananda