# What are the after-effects of insulting gods or goddesses?

Tags: karma, sin, smriti

I'm witnessing upsurge in sacrileges, such as—

- Demolishing idols of devatā-s or devī-s.
- Profane acts targeting iconography of devatā-s or devī-s.
- Making abusive versions of epics, purāṇa-s, etc.

I wonder, what are the consequences of such actions? or in other words, what are the sins attached to blasphemy?

Comment: sometimes when you see people suffering for no reason, like an accident, or handicap, we feel pity on them and try to help them - yes, we should do that, but when the questions arises - why did they suffer in the first place ? then karma has the answer - they did some papa in the past lives and are experiencing its results now. same logic goes for people who are enjoying great luck in this life, it means they did punya earlier. btw, Garuda purana has a lot of act+consequence u're looking for

Comment: @ram ""for people who are enjoying great luck in this life..."" - So that means they accumulated Punyas only to be bad. If Punya is making them do bad, then is it Punya or rather a miserably strong Paapam.

Comment: @AnuragSingh, they didn't accumulate Punyas IN ORDER TO BE bad. They are bad INSPITE of punyas, that means they acquired some new vasanas in this birth, or the vasanas were lying dormant and because of their great luck, they have the audacity to do bad things without realizing that they will be paying for it in future. Btw this pitfall exists only if you do punyas for the sake of acquiring merit. But if you do punyas for sake of pleasing God, this pitfall doesn't exist.

Comment: @ram Yes I agree. THIS PLAY OF MAYA. It is really hard to comprehend. This disport of Fate, Karma, Time, is hard to be understood.

Comment: If they don't know about our god's as they are Non Hindu, so in that case we who come across with them should politely make them understand, I hope not immediately but later they may change their mind. If you don't do this then you may also have a sin

Comment: Understandable! Well according to my understanding of Mahabharath, `I believe in Karma.., you have your will, do whatever you want, but be prepared for the consequences`. Killing cow is a sin (Gau Hatya) and it has its own punishment! But apart from Indra dev, I never read about any avatar's or the trinity's forcing any being(living/non-living) to pray them!

Comment: "Killing cows intentionally" - cow is not a god/goddess, you should remove this statement. That's a separate question in itself.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A punishment which one has to face in the afterlife is given in [**Devi Bhagavata Purana 9.33.**](http://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatam51-2.htm)

> The wretch that abuses Mûla Prakriti, the Vedas, the S’âstras,
>   Purânas, Brahmâ, Visnu, S’iva and the other Devas, Gaurî, Laksmî,
>   Sarasvatî and the other Devîs, **goes to the hell named Bhayânaka
>   Narakakunda. There is no other hell more tormenting than this**. The
>   sinners live here for many Kalpas and ultimately become serpents.
>   There is no sin greater than the abuse of the Devî. There is no
>   expiation for it. So one ought never to abuse the Devî. If one
>   discontinues the allowances given by oneself or other persons to the
>   Devas or Brâhmanas, one goes to Visthâ Kunda and has to eat the faeces
>   there for sixty thousand years and finally to be born in Bhârata as worms in faeces the same number of
>   years.

This includes punishments for abusing both deities and the scriptures.

Comment: Hinduism says so about dieties and Scriptures....Does hinduism tells about abusing people..Like serious abuse, slangs and also on making jokes on people for fun and leg pulling, etc. I don't think this used to happen in the past(vedic era).

Comment: @LSSJBroly You can see this -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15460/4732

Comment: What about the light jokes which people throw on others? What if the person for whom the joke is, feels bad? Does it count as 'papa' for the speaker? Just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Obviously it is not good to offend and humiliate others .. our conscience tells us that @LSSJBroly

Comment: Is there a prāyaścitta for devanindā (nindā of devatās)?

Comment: Haven't seen anything specific @Bingming

Answer (score 12):

Such actions can be done in following ways:

### Unintentional

One doesn't intend to harm, but due to some indirect actions, a person ends up damaging something. This doesn't result in anything as there was no purpose behind it. Some people feel sorry and some don't. Both are OK.

The Qn is not about this category, so not discussing much.

### Intentional

Many have the only ability to hate, they simply can't love. Hence they use this "hate" as a tool to worship God. If they are serious about what they are doing with single pointed steadfastness, then it's a kind of devotion (*Bhakti*).  Which is called ***Shatru Bhakti***. i.e. Worshipping god by animosity

Ultimately this hateful person either wants to kill the god or wants get killed by that god. Examples:

- ShishupAla:

  > And while Sisupala was speaking thus, the exalted slayer of Madhu thought in his mind of the discus that humbleth the pride of the Asuras. ...  the chief of the Yadus, that slayer of all foes, in anger, instantly cut off the head of the ruler of Chedi by means of his discus. And the mighty-armed one fell down like a cliff struck with thunder. And, O monarch, the assembled kings then beheld a fierce energy, like unto the sun in the sky, issue out of the body of the king of Chedi, and O king, **that energy then adored Krishna**, possessed of eyes like lotus leaves and worshipped by all the worlds, and **entered his body**. And all the kings beholding the energy which entered that mighty-armed chief of men regarded it as wonderful.  [[source]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02044.htm)
- RAvana -- see [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20532/1049), how Rama turned Ravana into nothingness

Whichever god we love or hate, we end up merging with them. Depending on emotion, the merger would be either pleasant or despicable.

### Ignorance

Now some people simply deride the god to have some distorted fun.
Yes, this is also a worshipping like above, but it's not steadfast or serious. Such people get their dues exactly in the same way due to Karma.

> BG 4.11 - **The way they approach Me, exactly in same way I serve them**; O Partha, all human beings follow My path in every way.
>   BG 9.11 - Ignorant people who have taken a human body, make fun of Me, not knowing My supreme nature as the Lord of all beings

Answer (score 12):

From Shiva Gita, Virodhi Bhakti too if in excess resulting into devotion, can become cause of liberation.

> अनादरेण शाठ्येन परिहासेन मायया . शिवभक्तिरतश्चेत्स्यादन्त्यजोऽपि विमुच्यते [21] 
>   Anyone while doing criticism, or while disrespecting, or due to jealousy, if gets devoted or gains devotion for Shiva, he would get cleansed of all the Sins immediately.

Comment: I don't understand the logic. So if I hate Rama because I love Ravana, I would get closer to Rama instead of Ravana?

Comment: ,@sv. Yes, if day in and day out, all you're thinking about is Sriman Narayana, if your mind is utterly consumed by him, then even if those thoughts are in the form of hate rather than love that can lead to Moksha.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan He doesn't believe in Sabda PramAn. Moreover, I am also selective in believing Sabda PramAn.

Comment: @Rajas. You should believe Sabda Pramana in all matters in which it does not contradict Pratyaksha and Anumana.  If you're not convinced of this, I suggest you read Shabara's commentary on the Purva Mimamsa Sutras.

Comment: Which part to read? Don't have time to read all. @KeshavSrinivasan

Comment: @Rajas. Read the part of his Bhashya on Adhyaya 1 Pada 1 of the Purva Mimamsa Sutras.  That establishes the Pramanya and Apaurusheyatva of the Vedas.  (The Pramanya of Smriti is established later on, in Adhyaya 1 Pada 3.)

Answer (score 4):

Excessive thinking of Lord even in the mood of hated/abuse results in Moksha only.

> **By enmity or by devotional service, by fear, by affection or by lusty
> desire — by all of these or any one of them — if a conditioned soul
> somehow or other concentrates his mind upon the Lord, the result is
> the same, for the Lord, because of His blissful position, is never
> affected by enmity or friendship**.(SB 7.1.26)
>
> **Many, many persons have attained liberation simply by thinking of
> Kṛṣṇa** with great attention and giving up sinful activities. **This great
> attention may be due to lusty desires, inimical feelings, fear,
> affection or devotional service.** I shall now explain how one receives
> Kṛṣṇa’s mercy simply by concentrating one’s mind upon Him. My dear
> King Yudhiṣṭhira, the gopīs by their lusty desires, **Kaṁsa by his fear,
> Śiśupāla and other kings by envy**, the Yadus by their familial
> relationship with Kṛṣṇa, you Pāṇḍavas by your great affection for
> Kṛṣṇa, and we, the general devotees, by our devotional service, have
> obtained the mercy of Kṛṣṇa. **Somehow or other, one must consider the
> form of Kṛṣṇa very seriously. Then, by one of the five different
> processes mentioned above, one can return home**, back to Godhead.
> Therefore, one must somehow think of Kṛṣṇa, whether in a friendly way
> or inimically.(SB 7.1.30-32)