# Punishment for Blasphemy?

Tags: manu-smriti, smriti, punishment, immortality, parashara-smriti

Is there any punishment for blasphemy in Hinduism? Do any scriptures or Smritis say how a King or a government should punish the blasphemer?

The speaker of [This video](https://youtu.be/8PLy4dEla6o?t=1800s), Henry Doktorski, claims the following.

> **In the Vedic scriptures, in several places, it is said that a blasphemer should be killed with no punishment awarded to the
> executioner.** So they were like going back and this ancient mythology
> and you know like they don't realize that they are living in a whole
> new society. Now you know but that was the thing to re-establish this
> ancient (ancient) culture that was one of the things and they
> eventually you know caught up to the guy and killed him.

Is this true?

Comment: Please quote exactly what the speaker(s) are saying. And then your exact doubt.

Comment: 1. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19134/what-are-the-after-effects-of-insulting-gods-or-goddesses

2. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22871/are-there-any-blasphemy-laws-in-the-dharma-%c5%9b%c4%81stras

Comment: I edited your question, is it okay for you?

Comment: hinduism is relligion where atheist is also called as adrent hindu.. there 21 different school of thought.. and philosophy but what is common they all believe in reincarnation which abrahmic releigion doesnt.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There is prescription of hell for such people.

> A sinner **who slanders Brahma, the creator of the world, the goddess Durga who is the best of female deities, Laksmi, Saraswati, Sita, Tulsi, Ganga, the Vedas, the mother of the Vedas, a vow, devotion, mystic formula pertaining to worship of the spiritual guide who gives formula will dwell in the hell called the ‘Blind well’** for half the period of the longevity allotted to Brahma, where bitten by snakes he will scream dreadfully.

> > **[Brahma Vaivarta Purana, Krishna Janma Khanda 40.116-141]**

But unlike Abrahamic religions I don't think any scripture ask Hindus to go and kill or punish blashempous people directly.