# What will happen to the person who disrespect others' beliefs (other religions)?

Tags: karma, other-religions

When a hindu disrespect or hurt the religious sentiments of a person that belongs to other religions (like Islam or Christianity) will he/she get bad karma?

And is the punishment for this same as disrespecting hindu Gods and Goddess?
Does hindu scriptures talk anything about disrespecting other's religious beliefs or practices?

---

<sup>[Blasphemy in Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19134/22556), it only answers if one disrespect **hindu** Gods.</sup>

Comment: How can this be a person advise. Can you explain, all those who have voted to close this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scriptures always ask to act as per Dharma and cause minimum harm to others even in thoughts. If we disrespect other religions or hurt their beliefs, its Adharma.

> **For Virtue and Sin do not go about and say, 'Here we are'**; nor do gods, Gāndharvas, or Manes say to men, 'This is Dharma, that is
> Adharma.' But that is Dharma, the practice of which the noble ones
> praise; what they blame, is Adharma. (Apastamba 1.7.20.6-7)
>
> The Eternal Duty towards all creatures is the **absence of malevolence
> towards them in thought, deed or word**, and to practice compassion
> and charity towards them. (MB Vana 297.35)
>
> In act, mind and speech **he shall carefully do what is right; and he
> shall not do what is right if** it happens to he such as is not
> conducive to heaven, or **disapproved by the people**.(Yajnavalkya
> 1.156)
>
> Brihaspati says ”That man who practices the religion of universal
> compassion achieves his highest good . **One should never do that to
> another, which one regards as injurious to one’s own self. This, in
> brief, is the rule of righteousness**.”(MB Anu CXIII)
>
> What is ultimately good for the welfare of all beings is what I
> consider as Truth(MB Shanti 329.13).

Since disrespecting and insulting religious sentiments of other religions causes unhappiness to others, it is Adharma. There are many statements in the Scripturas which say all religions including all Non Vedic lead to same truth because its made by Omniscient being. Hence we must to avoid Adharma of disrespecting other religions. Few of such verses which say all Non Vedic lead to same truth are :-

> A**ll Vedic and Non Vedic Shastras and many more Sastras, the Omniscient
> Divine Being has made in brief**.The wise say that **each of these sastras
> is intended for a particular class according to the individual
> qualification**, not all for one. As all streams ultimately empty
> themselves into the ocean, so all these paths ultimately lead to the
> Mahesvara Himself. **Worshipped in what form so ever by people as
> ordained in their respective scriptures. He assumes that form and
> takes the devotee on to the next higher step, By His Grace man attains
> to superior paths. Thus these paths, laid out as they are by Shiva,
> are all of them true and serviceable**. Shiva is supremely merciful,
> omniscient, and altogether stainless. Yet of all the paths, the path
> of the Veda is the best as conducing to all good." (Chapter 22, Yajna
> Vaibhava Khanda, Suta Samhita, Skanda Purana )

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Your most welcome @DarkKnight :)