# Some question about mahadev and devi parvati

Tags: shiva, parvati

1. why don't we circle full shivling and if we circle the shivling {parikrama}5-6times,what will happen (any way to repent to mahadev Or atoning) for it
2. if someone intentionally or unintentionally disrespect mahadev and parvati, what is the punishment? Any way to repent

Comment: (I have never disrespected God but around 6-7 age, I circled shivling alone in evening even after my parents telling not to do  ) 

Suggest mantras to repent and atoning to mahadev please

Comment: You can ask your second question as a separate question but even that will be a duplicate of - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19134/4732

Comment: That is not an issue as you were a kid then .. just bathing Shivling with water clears all sins.

Comment: @Rickross these are just believes if watering shivling could clear sins. Then all rakshas worshipping mahadev would be purified. Can you please suggest some mantras for atonement? Or some verses for repenting

Comment: How are you sure all Rakshasas are religious and do Shivalinga abhisekha? on a daily basis Just see around us .. how many humans are religious and do the same? Same for the Rakshasas. Those who do regular worship get their sins cleared.

Comment: You can chant Shivas mantras .. like Om shivaya namah counting it with rosary beads. Or Om tatpurushaya vidmahe mahadevaya dhimahi tanno rudra prachodayath

Comment: Or you can recite the Linga ashtakam which itself says that worshipping Shiva Linga clears all sins -- https://www.hindupedia.com/en/Linga_Ashtakam

Comment: Another Stotram is the Shivaparadha kshamapana stotram (https://www.hindupedia.com/en/Shivaparadha_kshamapana_stotram) which is recited to ask for forgiveness from Lord Shiva for any offence committed.