What is the punishment of insulting God and devtas?
What should be done if someone insults Lord Vishnu Lord Shiv or any devta?

This question is similar to: Are there any blasphemy laws in the dharma śāstras?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

A duplicate of -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19134

The punishment is spoken by Sati devi in Srimad Bhagavatam 4.4.17 when Daksha Prajapati insulted Lord Shiva.
कर्णौ पिधाय निरयाद्यदकल्प ईशे धर्मावितर्यसृणिभिर्नृभिरस्यमाने ।
छिन्द्यात्प्रसह्य रुशतीमसतीं प्रभुश्चे- ज्जिह्वामसूनपि ततो विसृजेत्स
धर्म: ॥ १७ ॥


Satī continued: If one hears an irresponsible person blaspheme the
master and controller of religion, one should block his ears and go
away if unable to punish him. But if one is able to kill, then one
should by force cut out the blasphemer’s tongue and kill the offender,
and after that one should give up his own life.

