# Has the Anukramani of the Shukla Yajur Veda ever been published in any form?

Tags: vedas, translation-request, rishi, yajur-veda

Each of the four Vedas consists of four parts: Samhitas, Brahmanas, Aranyakas and Upanishads.  But the core of the Vedas is the Samhitas, which consist of verses heard directly from the gods by sages called Dhristas (literally "seers").  These verses were compiled by the sage Krishna Dwaipayana Veda Vyasa into the books that we call the Vedic Samhitas.  Now associated with each Samhita is a systematic index called an [Anukramani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anukrama%E1%B9%87%C4%AB).  The Anukramanis, compiled by sages in ancient times, document, among other things, the sage who heard each verse from the gods, and the deity that each verse is addressed to.  In [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2430/36), with a lot of effort I was able to compile this Anukramani information for most of the hymns of the Rig Veda Samhita.

But now my question is, where can I get the Anukramani of the Shukla Yajur Veda?  (There are two versions of the Yajur Veda, the Shukla or "white" version and the Krishna or "black" version.)  The reason I ask is that in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2826/36) I'm trying to find out the sage who heard the Isha Upanishad, which is the only Upanishad that is part of the Samhitas of the Vedas, specifically the Samhita of the Shukla Yajur Veda.

Now the Samhita of the Shukla Yajur Veda is called the [Vajasaneyi Samhita](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yajurveda#Shukla_Yajurveda), and there are two Shakhas or recensions of the Samhita, the Madhyandina Shakha and the Kanva Shakha.  And apparently there does exist an Anukramani of the Madhyandina version of the Samhita, authored by the sage Katyayana.  Here's what [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=U-1jAAAAMAAJ&lpg=PA226&ots=r_4-hcpfoY&dq=katyayana%20anukramani%20madhyandina&pg=PA226#v=onepage&q=katyayana%20anukramani%20madhyandina&f=false) says:

> For the Yajur Veda we have three Anukramanis... The third Anukramani, that of the Madhyandina-Shakha of the Vajasaneyaka, is ascribed to Katyayana, who is mentioned also as the author of an Anuvakanukramani. It gives the names of the poets, the deities, and the meters, for all the verses of the Samhita, including the Khila (Adhyaya 26-35), and the Sukriya portions (Adhyaya 36-40).

[This book](http://books.google.com/books?id=DmlFAAAAYAAJ&dq=madhyandina%20anukramani&pg=PA208#v=onepage&q=madhyandina%20anukramani&f=false) says the same thing:

> The Yajur Veda has three Anukramanis, viz. one for the Atreya recession of the Black Yajur Veda, one for the recension of the Charakas, and **the third for the Madhyandina recension of the White Yajur Veda**.

But these books don't seem to mention anything about where Katyayana's Anukramani of the Madhyandina recension has been published.  For my previous question about the Rig Veda Anukramani, I specifically wanted the Anukramani online in English. But here I'm much more desperate, because I can't find it in any form.  So I just want to know whether it's been published *at all*, whether in book form or online, whether in Sanskrit or in English translation.

Note that the Anukramanis contain lots of other information about each verse, like the poetic meter and the like, but all I really want from the Anukramani of the Shukla Yajur Veda is the sage and deity information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Anukramani of Shukla Yajurveda Vajasaneyi Samhita is available in this book named [**Yajurveda Samhita.**](https://vedpuran.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/yajurved.pdf) It gives "Prakaran" which means to which ritualistic purpose is it used, "Rishi" which means who heard the mantras, "Devata" which means to which God is it addressed and "Chhanda" which means in which Vedic metre are the mantras. The book contains Sanskrit mantras in Devanagari script with Hindi translation of the mantras.

Prakarana and 2nd Level of Rishi is avaliable in page no. 13 of this book.

Devata and 3rd Level of Rishi is avaliable just after each chapter is finished.

As I discuss in my [answer here,](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2826/who-is-the-seer-of-the-isha-upanishad/14443#14443) there are three level of Rishis for Vajasaneyi Samhita.

1) 1st level of Rishi:

> इषेत्वादि खं ब्रह्मान्त विवस्वान् ।।
>   It was taught by Vivasvan (hence he is the Rishi).

**Thus the Rishi for whole Vajasaneyi Samhita is Rishi Vivasvan.**

2) 2nd level of Rishi:

> ततः प्रतिकर्म - विभागेन ब्राह्मणानुसारेण ऋषयो वेदितव्या ।।
>   Thus the ritualistic division as per the Brahmana and they are Rishi.

They are DarshaPurnamasha Prakaran Rishi and are of Deva level (except Yajnavalkya and Dadhichi) and they are Rishi due to division by Brahmana Grantha. It is avaliable in page no. 13 of the above book.

3) 3rd level of Rishi:
They are called Rishi due to mastery in respective Vedic mantras. They are called Vaiyektika Stara Sambaddha Rishi. It is available just after each chapter ends.

For those who can't read Devanagari script (Sanskrit/ Hindi), I have compiled here information about 2nd level of Rishi and in which prakarana (ritual) they are used:

> [**Ritual** // Chapter // **Rishi** ]
>
> [Darshapurnamasa// **1.1- 2.28** // ParamesthiPrajapati or Devagana Prajapati]
>   
>   [Pitriyajna// **2.29 - 2.34** // Prajapati ]
>   
>   [Ajnyaadheya// **3.1- 3.8**// Prajapati, DevaSena, Agni or Gandharva]
>   
>   [Agnihotra// **3.9 - 3.10** // Prajapati]
>   
>   [Yajamanagni Upasthan// **3.11- 3.36** // Devagana]
>   
>   [Aagotopasthan// **3.37 - 3.43** // Aditya ]
>   
>   [Chaturmasya// **3.44 - 3.63** // Prajapati]
>   
>   [Agnistoma// **4.1 - 8.32** // Prajapati]
>   
>   [Satropasthan// **8.51- 8.53** // Devagana]
>   
>   [Naimittika// **8.54 - 8.63** // Vasistha ]
>   
>   [Vajapeya// **9.1- 9.34**// Brihaspati-Indra]
>   
>   [Rajasuya// **9.35- 10.30** // Varuna ]
>   
>   [Charaksautramani// **10.31- 10.34** // Ashwinikumar]
>   
>   [Agnichayan// **11-18** // Prajapati/Sadhyagana]
>   
>   [Sautramani// **19-21** // Prajapati]
>   
>   [Ashwamedha// **22-25 and 29th chapter** //Prajapati]
>   
>   [Agnikodhya// **27** // Prajapati]
>   
>   [Purushmedha// **30-31** // Narayanpurusha]
>   
>   [Sarvamedha// **32** // Brahma Swayambhu]
>   
>   [Anarabhyadhit// **33.55 - 34.58** // Aditya- Yajnavalkya]
>   
>   [Pitrodhyaa// **35** // Aditya/Devagana]
>   
>   [Pravaryagnikascha Medhopanisat// **36** // Dadhyang Atharvan]
>   
>   [Mahabir Sambharan Prokshanati// **37** // Dadhyang Atharvan]
>   
>   [Mahabir Nirupane Dharmadugtohanam// **38** // Dadhyang Atharvan]
>   
>   [Pravargya Dharmabhede Prayaschit // **39** // Dadhyang Atharvan]
>   
>   [Ishavasyopanishad// **40** // Dadhyang Atharvan]

Comment: Wow, thanks! You wrote a much more detailed answer than I was expecting.

Comment: @Tezz  Thanks for , Hindi Yajurved samhita it will be much more easy for all to read and understanding.

Comment: Do you have any idea about [Is there any online Anukramanika (Index of Sages and deities) for Krishna Yajurveda?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19048/277)?