# Who are the seers of narayana suktam and sri rudram/shat rudriyam respectively?

Tags: vedas, vaishnavism, yajur-veda, shukla-yajurveda

They are the most prominent hymns for shaiva and vaishnava traditions, but which sage heard them?

Comment: [Narayana Sukta](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/narayanasukta.html?lang=sa) is found at Taittariya Aaranyaka 4, Prapathaka 10, Anuvaaka 13, Are you talking about Purusha Suktam? which is found in Rigveda and Yajurveda Samhita.

Comment: Regarding [Sri Rudram](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/rudram.html?lang=sa), it is found at (Krishna Yajurvediya) Taittariya Samhita 4th Kanda, 7th Prapathaka. And question about Anukramani of Rishi and Deva is [posted](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19048/277).