# In what circumstances Yagnopavita must be changed?

Tags: scripture, dharma, yagnopavitam

Janeu the sacred Yagyopavita thread is worn by any dwija who wishes to follow some set of rules. So,

- what are those rules and in which scripture they  are described?
- In what circumstances a Yajyopavit has to be changed?

Comment: Also, see [Is Janeva (Yajñopavītam or sacred thread) limited to Brahmins only?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2892/2995)

Comment: Another related question which addresses the 2nd part of your question (when can it be changed): [What scripture does the sacred thread mantra come from?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2784/2995)