# About the rules of changing yagyopaveetam

Tags: vedas, manu-smriti, puja, yagnopavitam

Can we change our poonal or janeu(sacred thread) on bhadra kaal which is on 30th august 2023.
if yes, then the right timing for changing?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditions for changing sacred thread?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17581/conditions-for-changing-sacred-thread)