# Why is the divine architect Vishwakarma considered a descendant of Bhrigu?

Tags: rishi, vedic-gods, ancestry, vishwakarma

Every Brahmin is a descendant of sages, which is why every Gotra or clan of Brahmins has an associated list of Pravaras, a list of the sages they're descended from.  For instance, I am a Brahmana belonging to Vadhula Gotra, and my Pravaras are "Bhargava, Vaitahavya, Savedasa", which means that I am descended from the sages Bhrigu, Vitahavya (whom I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7122/36)), and Savedasa.  In any case, I was looking at Wikipedia’s [list of Pravaras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pravaras) for various Gotra, when I came across the following Pravaras for Bhargava Gotra:

> 19. Bhargava:Bhargava,Abnavana/Tvashta/Ahabhuna,Vishvaroopa

For those who don't know, Tvashta, also known as Vishwakarma, is the architect of the gods.  As I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7395/36), he built Indra's city of Amaravati, Ravana's city of Lanka, and Krishna's city of Dwaraka, and he once caused the Earth to submerge!  And Vishvaroopa, also known as Trisiras was the three-headed son of Tvashta, As I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2408/36), Indra killed Trisiras, and to take revenge Tvashta created a demon called Vritrasura to kill Indra.  Indra ultimately killed Vritrasura, and it is this deed that Indra was most famous for in ancient times.

But my question is, why would Tvashta and Trisiras be listed in the Pravaras for Bhargava Gotra?  That means that Brahmins belonging to Bhargava Gotra are descended from them.  But Bhargava means descendant of Bhrigu, and Tvashta isn't a descendant of Bhrig at all; he's one of the Adityas or sons of Kashyapa and Aditi, as described in this chapter of the Srimad Bhagavatam:

> The names of the sons of Aditi are as follows: Vivasvān, Aryamā, Pūṣā, Tvaṣṭā, Savitā, Bhaga, Dhātā, Vidhātā, Varuṇa, Mitra, Śatru and Urukrama.... Racanā, the daughter of the Daityas, became the wife of Prajāpati Tvaṣṭā. By his semen he begot in her womb two very powerful sons named Sanniveśa and Viśvarūpa.

Thus Tvashta would be classified as a Kashyapa, not a Bhargava.  So why would he be listed in the Pravaras for Bhargava Gotra?

Note that in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9017/36), I discuss a community of metalworkers and craftsmen who are considered low-caste by many people, but who claim to be Brahmanas descended from Vishwakarma.  But they're claims are considered unfounded, whereas Bhargava Gotra is a well-established Brahmana Gotra.  So I'm not sure if there's a connection.  Also, there is of course the possibility that Wikipedia has incorrect information, so does anyone know whether this set of Pravaras is mentioned in Hindu scripture?

EDIT: [This excerpt](http://gdurl.com/SDsS) from the Upodhgata Pada of the Brahmanda Purana says that Tvashta and Trisiras are the son and grandson of Bhrigu's son Sukracharya, guru of the Asuras:

> The mental daughter of the Manes named Somapas (imbibers of the Soma juice) was well-known by the name of Gau.  She became the wife of Shukra and gave birth to his four sons.  They were Tvashtar, Varatrin, Shanda, and Marka.... Trishiras alias Vishvarupa was the great (elder) son of Tvashtar.    He was born of Yashodhara, daughter of Virochana.  He became very famous.

How can this be reconciled with the statements that Tvashta one of the twelve sons of Kashyapa and Aditi?  Was he initially born as the son of Kashyapa and then reborn as the son of Sukracharya or vice versa?  Are there any scriptures that discuss this?

Comment: Are the pravara rishis necessarily of the same family, like for eg my Pravara is Vaisvamitra, Aghamarshana and Kaushika; out of whom Aghamarshana is someone else... at least I have mot heard any Aghamarshana in relation to Vishvamitra. So it could be like that. Sorry if I am wrong.

Comment: @Surya No, they are of the same family.  Aghamarshana was a descendant of Madhuchandas; see the Rig Veda Anukramani for Book 10 Hymn 190 (which is the famous Aghamarshana Sukta used for the purification of sins): http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2430/36 And Madhuchandas was a descendant of Vishwamitra; he is the seer of Rig Veda Book 1 Hymn 1, the famous "agnimile purohitam" hymn.

Comment: @Surya I've now found a scriptural basis for Tvashta being a descendant of Bhrigu; see my edit.

Comment: Maybe there were two Tvashtas.

Comment: @Surya Two people named Tvashta who both have sons named Trisiras and their sons named Trisiras are both known also as Vishwarupa?  That's too much in common to be a coincidence.  So I think the most likely explanation is that the father and son were reborn.

Comment: What makes you think being reborn to the same parents with the same name is more logical than the other? :p

Comment: @Surya Well, that's a well-documented phenomenon in the Puranas, someone being reborn with the same name and having the same basic biographical details.  It's happened with many rishis.  And Tvashta is a rishi.

Comment: @Surya You may be interested in this question I just posted about another strange set of Pravaras: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10209/36

Comment: I think there is a possibility that Tvashtar was also a title like that of Indra. The Tvashtar for the Daityas was the son of Shukracharya while the Tvashtar of the gods was the Aditya VIshwakarma.

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal The architect of the Asuras is Maya.

Comment: Ya that I know but then even Maya is not just one person right there are different Asuras of that name. In fact the entire Vritra story also makes sense is if Tvashtar was an ally of the Asuras rather than an Aditya,