# In which scriptures are the verses ''aham brahmasmi" and ''shivoham'' found?

Tags: scripture, shiva, brahman, advaita, identification-request

In which scripture are the following verses found:

> Aham brahmasmi
>   **Meaning:** I am Brahma
>
> Shivoham
>   **Meaning:** I am Shiva

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Mahavakyas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11896/3500)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is an Vedantic verse taken from an upanishad. Another is probably non Vedic and appears in famous "NirvAna shatakam" stotra.

> Tat Tvam Asi (Sanskrit: तत् त्वम् असि or तत्त्वमसि, "Thou art that,"
>   "That thou art," or "You are that") — is one of the Mahāvākyas (Grand
>   Pronouncements).
>
> It originally occurs in the Chandogya Upanishad 6.8.7, in the dialogue
>   between Uddālaka and his son Śvetaketu; it appears at the end of a
>   section, and is repeated at the end of the subsequent sections as a
>   refrain. The meaning of this saying is that the Self - in its
>   original, pure, primordial state - is wholly or partially identifiable
>   or identical with the Ultimate Reality that is the ground and origin
>   of all phenomena. The knowledge that this is so characterises the
>   experience of liberation or salvation that accompanies the Unio
>   Mystica.

[Source](http://veda.wikidot.com/tat-tvam-asi)

न च व्योम भूमिर्न तेजो न वायुः

**चिदानन्दरूपः शिवोऽहम् शिवोऽहम् ॥१॥ Nirvana shatakam.**

however, Soham and other similar phrases are found in yogic and agamic literature.

> This sentence appears in the Brihadaranyaka Upanishad when the sage,
>   in the context of meditation on the Self, in reply to the query – What
>   did that Brahman know by which It became all? - states:-
>
> "ब्रह्म वा इदमग्र आसीत्, तदात्मनामेवावेत्, अहं ब्रह्मास्मीति |
>
> तस्मात्तत्सर्वमभवत्; तद्यो यो देवानां प्रत्यबुध्यत स एव तदभवत्,
>   तदषीर्णाम् तथा मनुष्याणाम्,..."
>
> "This (self) was indeed Brahman in the beginning; It knew only Itself
>   as, "I am Brahman". Therefore It became all; and whoever among the
>   gods knew It also became That; and the same with sages and men…” -
>   (Brihadaranyaka Upanishad I.iv.10)

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aham_Brahmasmi)

There are multiple interpretations of these phrases.