# How important are the Mahavakyas in different traditions?

Tags: mahavakyas

1. Prajñānaṃ Brahma (प्रज्ञानं ब्रह्म)
   From Aitareya Upanishad 3.3 of the Rig Veda."(pure) consciousness of Brahman"
2. Tat Tvam Asi (तत्त्वमसि)
   From Chandogya Upanishad 6.8.7 of the Sama Veda "You are that (Brahman)".
3. Ahaṃ Brahmāsmi (अहं ब्रह्मास्मि)
   From Brhadaranyaka Upanishad 1.4.10 of the Yajur Veda "I am Brahman."
4. Ayaṃ Ātmā Brahma (अयं आत्माब्रह्म)
   From Mandukya Upanishad 1.2 of the Atharva Veda "The self (Atman) is Brahman."

These are traditionally considered Mahavakyas (great sayings) of the Upanishads.

The immensely popular religious speaker Dushyanth Sridar says in this Tamil/Kannada discourse that

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwSWW9kY2es 9:43

these Mahavakyas are of no special importance in the Vishishtadvaita tradition.

What is his basis for this claim?

Are these sayings of primary importance only in the Advaitic tradition?

Comment: Check a similar question I asked: [What is the significance of the Mahavakyas in non-Shankara Advaitic philosophies?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53061/what-is-the-significance-of-the-mahavakyas-in-non-shankara-advaitic-philosophies)