# Why is the Rig Veda Samhita important?

Tags: rig-veda

Why is the Rig Veda Samhita important?

Most of the Samhita praises Indra and talks about the Soma yajna, which no one does anymore today.

The Smriti is more relevant today.

Comment: Veda Samhita are Aparusheya and Rig-Veda is the oldest and biggest. Also visit [What are the basic facts and summary of what the Rigveda is about?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/4088/277)

Comment: everyone should do it. so follow veda, not vedaanta

Comment: Vedas  actually also have spiritual  meaning and they are important because  all scriptures  including Puranas,Mahabharata,Ramayana,Smritis too consider vedas(including rig veda to be highest).in Rig Veda too all verses are actually spiritual also but difficult to understand it s meaning,that's why upanishads are there which explain a lot.