# Base pillars of hinduism

Tags: scripture

Which are the base pillars of Hindu culture?
As per my knowledge, there are

Bhagvat Geeta,

4 Vedas (Please add names)

18 Puranas (Please add names)

16 Shastras (please add name)

Smarities,and more...

Will you please complete these? and where can I get all these scriptures to learn?

Comment: There's ithihasas like mahabharata, ramayana, etc. Then there are moksha sastras such as Upanishads, Brahma Sutras, Patanjali's Yoga Sutras, Bhagavad Gita. All the best sir

Comment: See my answer here for links to the Vedas: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/781/36

Comment: Vedanta sits on three pillars, or legs, The Brahma Sutras, the Upanishads, and the Gita.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, This is not the duplicate question, I am expecting the list of hindu (Shindhu) scriptures on which our culture is based on. Vedas are one of them.

Comment: @LaxmikantDange It seems like a duplicate question to me. What's the difference between the set of scriptures that every Hindu should abide by and the set of scriptures that are the pillars of Hinduism?