# Where can I find the authentic and complete Vedas online? [Hindi + English]

Tags: vedas, translation-request

There are various sources of Vedas available online but I'd like to know what is the most authentic source of Vedas, which haven't been manipulated and are complete to the best of our knowledge.

Also, if these are available online in Hindi + English along with the original Sanskrit text.

Comment: I think this is not fit for the main site, perhaps you can ask such questions on meta

Comment: I think this may be useful http://vedpuran.net/download-all-ved-and-puran-pdf-hindi-free/

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How did the Vedas in Hinduism come into existence?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/774/2995) [This answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/781/2995) has several links to online repository of Vedas.