# Praying original mantra vs praying with the meaning of mantra in different languages

Tags: practice, worship, mantras

Does praying or worshipping with the meanings of Mantras (or translation) in other languages give an equivalent results?

For example praying the original Gayatri Mantra and praying it's meaning in other languages say in Hindi give same result?

It could be any mantra.

Comment: Possible this question already been answered.-.https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13874/does-hinduism-allow-chanting-translated-vedic-mantras/18522#18522

Comment: See.  @The Destroyer's answer.

Comment: It is the sound, the 'vibration', which gives a mantra its power. It does need to be chanted in Sanskrit. If you know the meaning of the mantra, better, the intonation must be correct, knowing the meaning is not necessary. The vibration which it will work on you subtly is what counts. You get wet whether you fall into a pool of water, jump into it, or are pushed into it.