# Is phalashruti applicable to people who read translated versions?

Tags: worship, stotra, language

Many Hindu texts have phalashruti for even reading the texts or even for reading a single shloka of such texts.

In this context I got the doubt:

**Is phalashruti (for reading) applicable to those who read in the Sanskrit language only**?

If people are reading such texts in English or in their own local language then are they eligible to get the phalashruti for reading?

Comment: This is not answerable IMO .. people shd read the Sanskrit version along with understanding the meanings

Comment: I think it is already answered. Phala sruti is a summary on what happens if you read the stotra. It is not necessary to read the phala shruti. You should read in Sanskrit only if you want to get results. Related or duplicate of [Does Hinduism allow chanting translated Vedic mantras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13874/5212). See all the linked questions to that question.

Comment: By "reading of phalsruti" I think u meant "whatever that is written in the phalasruti" and not reading the phalasruti portion?

Comment: It is not advisable to read the Sanskrit mantras in translated versions

Comment: @Rickross No, reading whole text along with phalashrti.