# Timelines of Ramayana, Mahabharata, Vedas, and Upanishads

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, ramayana, upanishads

Can someone please give timelines of Ramayana, Mahabharta, Vedas, and Upanishads?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93816/discussion-on-question-by-viswanathan-sethuraman-timelines-of-ramayana-mahabhar).

Answer (score 4):

Klaus K. Klostermaier's [*A Concise Encyclopedia of Hinduism*](https://archive.org/stream/KlausK.KlostermaierAConciseEncyclopediaOfHinduismConciseEncyclopediaOfWorldFaiths_201612#page/n226/mode/1up) has the following traditional dates for Hindu scriptures starting with the Vedas.

> **Chronology**
>
> The chronology of Ancient India up to the time of Buddha is at present
>   the focus of fierce scholarly debates. The majority of Indian scholars
>   assume a date of 4000 BCE for the Ṛgveda, rejecting also the so-called
>   'Aryan invasion theory', whereas the majority of Western scholars
>   maintain the invasion theory and date the Ṛgveda to 1500–1200 BCE. **The
>   chronology offered here represents largely the traditional Indian
>   position.**
>
> Indians who do not use the Western (Gregorian) calendar have several
>   other systems of dating. The most common eras used in today's India
>   are *samvat* (beginning 57 BCE) and *śaka* (beginning 78 CE).
>
> On the basis of the more recent research, based on archaeology and
>   astronomy, the following chronology can be **tentatively** established:
>
> **c. 4000 BCE  Earliest Vedic hymns**
>
> c. 3500 BCE  Early Harappan civilization
>
> c. 3100 BCE  Traditional dates for the 'Great Flood' and Manu
>   Vaivasvata
>
> c. 3000–2750 BCE  Traditional date for Yayāti Period
>
> c. 2750–2550 BCE  Traditional date for Māndhātri Period
>
> c. 2700–1500 BCE  Mature Indus civilization
>
> **c. 2350–1950 BCE  Traditional date for Rāmacandra period**
>
> **c. 1900 BCE  Age of Rāmāyaṇa**
>
> **c. 1500–500 BCE  Major Upaniṣads, development of early Sāṃkhya, early Pūrva Mīmāṁsā**
>
> **c. 1400 BCE  Great Bharata War – Age of Kṛṣṇa. Early version of
>   Mahābhārata**
>
> c. 1200 BCE  Early Sūtra literature. Consolidation of Vedic civilization: Manusmṛti
>
> 624–544 BCE  Life of Gautama Buddha according to traditional reckoning
>
> 527 BCE  End of Mahāvīra's earthly life according to Jain tradition
>
> 518 BCE  Persian invasion under Skylax and conquest of the Indian satrapy for Darius I
>
> **c. 500 BCE–500 CE**  Composition of Śrauta Sūtras, Gṛhya Sūtras, Dharma Sūtras, Vedāṇgas; the basis of the orthodox systems; **composition of the epics and the original Purāṇas**
>
> **c. 500–200 BCE  Composition of the Bhagavad-gītā**
>
> c. 500–200 BCE  Bādarāyaṇa's Vedānta Sūtra
>
> c. 490–458 BCE  Reign of Ajātaśatru, king of Magadha
>
> c. 400 BCE  Pāṇini's Aṣṭādhyāyī (Grammar)
>
> c. 400–200 BCE  Jaimini's Pūrvamīmāṁsā Sūtra
>
> 327–325 BCE  Alexander of Macedonia's invasion of India
>
> c. 322–298 BCE  Reign of Candragupta of Magadha
>
> c. 300 BCE  Megasthenes, Greek Ambassador to Magadha
>
> c. 300 BCE  Kauṭilya's Arthaśāstra (according to some scholars: 100 CE) Gautama's Nyāya Sūtras and Kaṇāda's Vaiśeṣika Sūtra
>
> c. 273–237 BCE  Reign of Aśoka
>
> c. 200 BCE–100 CE  Invasions of Śuṅgas, Iranians, Śakas and
>   Kuṣāṇas, who founded kingdoms in India
>
> c. 200 BCE–200 CE  Peak period of Buddhist and Jain influence
>
> c. 150 BCE–100 CE  Patañjali's Mahābhāṣya
>
> c. 115 BCE  Besnagar inscription of Heliodorus with a mention of Kṛṣṇa worship
>
> c. 100 BCE–500 CE  Patañjali's Yoga Sūtra
>
> c. 100 BCE–100 CE  Upavarṣa's commentary on Pūrvamīmāṁsā Sūtra and Vedanta Sūtra
>
> c. 100 BCE–400 CE  Śabara-bhāṣya on Jaimini Sūtras
>
> c. 100 BCE–800 CE  Composition of Tirukkural
>
> c. 100 BCE  Early Mathura sculpture; images of gods in temples
>
> c. 25 BCE  Indian embassy to Emperor Augustus of Rome
>
> c. 50 CE  First documentation of images of gods with several pairs of arms
>
> c. 10  Indian embassy to Emperor Trajan of Rome
>
> c. 100–500  Expansion of Hinduism in South-East Asia
>
> c. 100–200  Yājñavalkyasmṛti
>
> c. 100–300  Viṣṇudharma Sūtra
>
> c. 100–400  Nāradasmṛti
>
> c. 200–500  Composition of Viṣṇu Purāṇa
>
> c. 250–325  Sāṃkhya Kārikā of Īśvarakṛṣṇa
>
> c. 300–600  Composition of some of the older Purāṇas in their present form
>
> c. 300–888  Pallava rulers in South India (Kāñcīpuram)
>
> c. 319–415  Gupta empire of Mathurā
>
> c. 400–500  Vātsyāyana's Kāma Sūtra
>
> c. 400  Composition of Harivaṃśa Purāṇa, Ahirbudhnya Saṃhitā. Age of Kalidāsa, the greatest Indian dramatist. Spread of Vaiṣṇavism, especially Kṛṣṇa cult. Beginning of Tantricism
>
> c. 400–500  Vyāsa's Yoga-bhāṣya
>
> ...

David R. Kinsley, in [*Hinduism: A Cultural Perspective*](https://archive.org/stream/hinduismcultural00kins#page/12/mode/2up), gave the following timeline that begins with the end of Indus Valley Civilization.

> [image: David Kinsley chronology]

A similar chronology is also available in [Encyclopedia of Hinduism](https://archive.org/stream/ConstanceA.JonesJamesD.RyanEncyclopediaOfHinduism#page/n27/mode/2up) by Constance A. Jones and James D. Ryan:

> 3600 B.C.E. to 1700 B.C.E.
>
> - Indus Valley civilization, including sites at Mohenjodaro and Harappa,
>     prospers. Archaeological finds include a seal that some scholars
>     identify as a proto-Shiva.
>
> 2050
>
> - Indo-Iranian people settle in Iran (Persia) and Afghanistan.
>
> 1900
>
> - Drying up of Sarasvati River due to climate changes. End of
>     Indus-Sarasvati culture; center of civilization in ancient India
>     relocates from the Sarasvati River to the Ganges River.
>
> 1500 B.C.E.
>
> - **Compilation of Rig Veda Samhita (the earliest extant text in
>     Hinduism)**.
>
> 1000 B.C.E.
>
> - **End of compilation of the three original Vedas: Rig, Yajur, and Sama**.
>
> 950
>
> - Decline of Sanskrit as a spoken language occurs over the next 300
>     years.
>
> 800 to 400 B.C.E.
>
> - **Orthodox Upanishads are compiled.**
>
> 750
>
> - Prakrits (vernacular or "natural" languages) develop among India's
>     various cultures, as evidenced from later Buddhist and Jain works.
>
> 599
>
> - Birth of Mahavira Vardhamana (c. 599–527), 24th Tirthankara, Jain
>     master who stresses vegetarianism, asceticism, and nonviolence.
>
> 563
>
> - Birth of Siddhartha Gautama (563–483), the Buddha.
>
> c. 500 to 200 B.C.E.
>
> - Over these 300 years numerous secondary Hindu scriptures (smriti) are
>     composed: Shrauta Sutras, Grihya Sutras, Dharma Sutras, **Mahabharata**,
>     **Ramayana**, puranas, and others.
>
> c. 450
>
> - Panini composes his Sanskrit grammar, the Ashtadhyayi.
>
> c. 400 B.C.E.
>
> - Dharmashastra of Manu develops. Its verses codify cosmogony, four
>     ashramas, government, domestic affairs, caste, and morality.
> - The Ajivikas, an ascetic, atheistic sect of naked sadhus reaches the
>     height of its popularity.
> - Adversaries of the Buddha and the Jain Mahavira, they have a
>     philosophy that is deterministic, holding that everything is
>     inevitable.
>
> ...

Comment: When you had opted for closing of  [my question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9009/3869) on the ground of speculation, you should have opted for closing this question also, as this question calls for data from history.  Why did not you do it?  May I know? @sv.

Comment: Does [this comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42483/is-there-any-reference-of-string-or-multi-verse-theory-in-hinduism#comment131356_42483) answer your question? The user there voluntarily deleted his question after reading my comment. @SrimannarayanaKV

Comment: I'm pasting the same comment here again for discussion: "Scientific speculation (searching for modern scientific discoveries in Hindu scripture, scientific reasons behind Hindu rituals/practices, etc.) is off-topic for this site. See [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/political-and-scientific-questions-are-off-topic-for-hinduism-se) meta post." @SrimannarayanaKV

Comment: Simply asking, How old is Ramayana, Bhagavad Gita, etc. can be answered using either Hindu scripture or as I did here, from books written by secular historians. Neither the question nor the answer engages in scientific speculation. Your question ('Did Ramayana occur 1.6 million years ago?') on the other hand has this line: "Modern anthropologists say that elephants with four tusks existed 12-1.6 million years ago." - you have now entered the scientific speculation zone and the accepted answer does not cite a single reference from Hindu scripture. @SrimannarayanaKV

Comment: Now to validate that answer, we need users from Biology SE and other science-centric SE sites. But those users don't visit this site. This is why we close questions that only expect answers from a purely science POV as off-topic ("scientific speculation"). The problem is not with the answer posted but the question seeking such an answer. I didn't understand this site rule very well back in 2015 when you asked the question, but after reading the answer it became clear the problem is with the question itself. Hope it's now clear. It's nothing personal. @SrimannarayanaKV

Comment: In the same analogy, the dates/timeline quoted in your answer under this question are pure speculation.  Who fixed the time period of Veda as 4000 BCE?  Western Indologists or Marxist oriented writers?  What is the basis for that?  Is not speculation?  You are adopting double standards here.  According to your principle, you should voluntarily delete your answer now. @sv.

Comment: Anyways, I am not as good as you are in using vocabulary.  I am a person with a limited vocabulary.  However, one thing I am sure about you.  You are applying different set of rules as per your convenience.  This is not fair.  Soon you will meet your worthy opponent in using good vocabulary and make you understand, what I could not, due to my own limitations.  Good luck @sv.

Comment: 'the dates/timeline quoted in your answer under this question are pure speculation' - it's the opinion of the author/historian. If you don't agree with their opinion you can downvote the answer. If you think quoting a historian is same as quoting a scientific journal then you can take it up on meta. I've no problem deleting my answer if the community decides to ban such answers. But again the problem here is with the question which is asking for timeline of Vedas, Ramayana, etc. Since Hindu scriptures don't cover such topics, one could argue the question itself is off-topic. @SrimannarayanaKV

Comment: If traditional answers like "Vedas are eternal, they cannot be dated" are the only type of answers allowed to such questions, then you can propose this rule on meta, get some votes, then I'll gladly delete this answer. @SrimannarayanaKV

Answer (score 1):

Rig veda II.15.6, dedicated to Indra,  says

> सोदञ्चं सिन्धुमरिणान महित्वा वज्रेणान उषसः सं पिपेष | अजवसो
> जविनीभिर्विव्र्श्चन सो... ||
>
> sodañcaṃ sindhumariṇān mahitvā vajreṇāna uṣasaḥ saṃ pipeṣa | ajavaso
> javinībhirvivṛścan so... ||
>
> With mighty power he made the ***Sindhu (stream) flow Northward/upward***, crushed
> with his thunderbolt the car of Uṣas, Rending her slow steeds with his
> rapid coursers. These things did Indra in the Soma's rapture.

The rishis composed the mantras of Rig Veda in esoteric manner.  So it is very difficult to say whether Indra's  act describes diversion of flow of **Sindhu in Northern direction** or in SPIRITUAL sense.

If it is viewed in physical sense, then the time period at which the direction of Sindhu was turned in Northern direction, is the period at which Rig Veda was composed.

May be lakhs of years ago.

---

The composition of Upanishads was done in Classical Sanskrit.  Hence, the time period for composition of Upanishads shall be around 600 BCE.

---

Ramayana occurred almost [16 lakh years ago](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9009/3869).  However, the composition of Ramayana was done in Classical Sanskrit, as was the case of Upanishads.  Hence, the time period for composition of Ramayana shall be around 600 BCE.

---

Mahabharata occurred much later.  It was [around 3100 BC](http://mahabharata-research.com/about%20the%20epic/dating%20the%20mahabharata%20war.html).