# How our great Maharishis did a concentration lots of time?

Tags: rishi, meditation

I have doubt on mind-concentration which is done by our great Rishi-munis in ancient time. I have tried to concentrate but I was disturbed in little time. What technique or method was he used to doing a concentrate?

**Note:** Here, I don't talk about tapasya. I Just try to understand what he did in the early morning.

Comment: Related: [What are the meditation techniques found in the scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/519/277) Also see [How did Rishis perform Tapasya (transcendental meditation) so that they heard Shruti/Veda?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17412/277)

Comment: @Pandya The linked questions don't *seem* to answer OP's question **as stated in the title**. I believe that *may* merit a separate response. **To Yogesh**: Are you asking how they managed to meditate for lengthy periods of time like thousands of years? What is your time scale?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did Rishis perform Tapasya (transcendental meditation) so that they heard Shruti/Veda?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17412/how-did-rishis-perform-tapasya-transcendental-meditation-so-that-they-heard-sh)

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan I don't want to know tapasya. I am wanted to know about he did in the early morning (timescale1-2 hours).

Comment: @YogeshBorad Makes sense, you should rephrase the question body to reflect this requirement.

Answer (score 2):

"deergha kaala nirantaraaya satkaaraasevitaH dhRaDha bhUmi"- Yogasutras,Patanjali.

The maharishis also achieved what you seek by practice, perseverance,patience,dedication and not giving up. It does not happen overnight.