# How many types of Vedas there ? And these are related to?

Tags: vedas

Every Vedas have separate knowledge. Please define

Comment: Pls. go through this answer - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/774/how-did-the-vedas-in-hinduism-come-into-existence/781#781

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 types of Vedas :

1. **RigVeda** : http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/index.htm
2. **YajurVeda** :  http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/index.htm (Krishna Version); 
                http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/wyv/index.htm (Shukla Version)
3. **SamaVeda** : http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sv.htm
4. **AtharvaVeda** : http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/index.htm