# Why is Ramayana called the adi-kavya (first poem) and not Rig Veda?

Tags: ramayana, rig-veda

Why is Ramayana called the adi-kavya (first poem) and not Rig Veda? As I understand Rig Veda also consist of poems and since Rig Veda is older than Ramayana, shouldn't it be called the first poem?

Comment: Rig Veda was not composed by a human, whereas Ramayana was.

Comment: Entire Ramayana is written in one meter.. but Rigveda has many meters...so entire Ramayana can be sung in one tune but Rigveda can't be sung in one tune...may be that's the reason because a poem ideally should be in one meter....

Comment: @YDS Well, by meter you mean chandass, there are different chandas used in Ramayana also.

Comment: Sarvabhouma See http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga2/bala_2_frame.htm entire Ramayana is supposed to be in one meter which can be sung...due to some interpolation or loss of the text etc...may be you noticed other meters...but ideally only anusthupa meter....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vedas and Kavyas are entirely different.

Vedas are called [Apaurusheya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apauru%E1%B9%A3ey%C4%81) which means authorless. [They were *heard*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/781/5212). Ramayana is a kavya *written* by man - Valmiki. Valmiki written the story of Rama using different words, analogies, embellishments, comparisons. Hence he is called Adi Kavi.

Rigveda consists of *mantras*. Verses in Vedas are called mantras. These are written in different meters. In Ramayana the verses are called shlokas (born from the shoka of Valmiki). A verse/poem is a blanket term used for a rhythmic/systematic arrangement which can be sung . But the words verse and poem also have a different meaning.

Just like there are features of Puranas, Kavya also has some features. Not every poem written by human author becomes a kavya. There are certain features to be fulfilled to become a poem.

For instance, according to [Mammata Bhatta](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/mammata)'s Kāvyaprakāśa, definition of Kāvya (poetry) is:

> tadadoṣau śabdārthau saguṇāvanalaṅkṛtī punaḥ kvāpi
>
> A combination of word and meaning, which is free of blemishes, endowed with qualities, alamkaras and sometimes the poetic figure is absent.

So which contains these features will be called a Kāvyaṃ. More definitions and information on a poem are found in relevant page on [wisdomlib.org](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/kavya)

There are several grammarians who gave their definition of Kāvya (poem) and some criticized Mammata's definition. However it's clear that a poem has different set of features. It contains embellishments, analogies, rhyming according to a proper meter etc., Rigveda on the other hand is not for reading with analogies, embellishments etc., there are seers who head the mantras due to a deep meditation technique.

Ramayana is the oldest literary work to be written with above features. Hence it is called Adi Kavya.

Answer (score 2):

Shodhganga's article  [***What is Kavya?***](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/154269/13/08_chapter%202.pdf), explains

> Imaginations  and  emotions  are  basic  concepts  of  Kavya 
>   (creative  literature)  which  are  often  expressed  in  metrical 
>   compositions.   Kavya  has  figurative  language,  typical  diction, 
>   nature,  and  words  in  various  combinations,  which  means  the 
>   choice  and  arrangement  of  words  and  their  structure.    Kavya   combines  pleasure  with  profit.     A  poet  uses  words  to 
>   produce  images.
>
> Kavya  excels  in  appealing  to  listeners  in broader  details.   Kavya has  special  characteristics.   It includes  all  creative 
>   literature  such  as  prose  and  verse.   It   is an  imaginative 
>   representation  of  life.   Imagination  and  emotion  are  basic 
>   concepts  of  Kavya.    The  emotional  interpretation  of  life  is 
>   presented  in  rhythmical  language.

---

Both Rig Vedic mantras and EPICs contain poems. The basic differences, in my view, between the Hymns in Rig Veda,say [Indra's eliminating Vritra](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv04018.htm), [Saraswati Suktam](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv06061.htm), etc, and EPICs like Ramayana, are that

- the Rig Vedic Hymns eulogise the Almighty God in esoteric/cryptic manner - understandable to spiritually elevated persons, whereas the EPIC like Ramayana is understandable to a common man also.
- the poems in EPICs like Ramayana were composed in Classic Sanskrit, whereas that of Rig Veda were composed in Vedic Sanskrit.
- The poems in Rig Veda may contain references to some historical figures like [Usana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv04026.htm) and do not contain any specific story except eulogising the Almighty in crypic manner, but the EPIC is all about the story of a central character ***with underlying theme***.
- In Ramayana the central character is Sri Rama, whereas the central Character of Mahabharata is Yudhisthira.  In both the EPICs the underlying theme is DHARMA.  Sri Rama and Yudhisthira were described by respective poets as **dharmAtma** - embodiment of Dharma (***rAmO vigrahavAn dharmaha***).
- the emotions that ordinary human beings carry, are depicted in a kaavya like Ramayana.

As the kaavya (EPIC) Ramayana, containing the story of Sri Rama,  was composed first, it is called Adi kAvya.

Comment: "Both Rig Vedic mantras and EPICs contain poems. " Mantra is a mantra, poem is a poem. Kavya translates to poem because a Kavi writes it. BTW, what reference is Shodhganga article citing for the definition?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma: It talks about what the Kavya is. That's why it  was referred to

Comment: I am asking about the definition. Where is the definition in the article  taken from? e.g Wikipedia provides a citation from a book. Similarly, did the article provide a reference?