# Where did we get Vedas from?

Tags: vedas

As the title suggests do we know who is the author of the four traditional Vedas namely Rig Veda, Sama Veda, Yajur Veda, Atharva Veda.

Also please suggest a good website for these books.

Comment: The Vedas do not have an author. The Vedas are apaurusheya.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did the Vedas in Hinduism come into existence?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/774/how-did-the-vedas-in-hinduism-come-into-existence)