# Location of Hindu Vedas

Tags: vedas

Where the original manuscript **(Since Vedas are not written by its creators themselves, First hand-written or most complete version)** of Hindu Vedas such as ‎Rigveda, Atharvaveda, ‎Yajurveda, ‎Samaveda are kept?

I heard someone saying that two of the most important Vedas are kept in a German Museum and the other two are kept in India.

Comment: My question is related to the physical location.

Comment: @Mr_Green This is not duplicate, this is good question, this guy is asking the location, not the origin.

Comment: It is true that Vedas were transmitted through memory and hearing, but they were written down during Adi Shankaracharya's time. This version is the "untampered" one and is either with Germany (taken away by Hitler's army), the Britishers or the U.S.A. Most of the "translated" version has lies inserted and many things omitted.

Answer (score 4):

I have mentioned this in the comments of my [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/where-are-the-original-versions-of-vedas). As this one is anyhow duplicate.

So the oldest known copies of Atharvaveda and Rigveda (2 of the 4 books) are kept at the [Bhandarkar Oriental Institute in Pune](http://www.bori.ac.in/), Maharashtra. These two manuscripts are written in Sanskrit and were found in Rajasthan during the late 1800's. They are dated from around 12-1300 AD and thus preceding any major Persian influences.

These manuscripts are included in the UNESCO list of world heritage sites and are commonly expected to be priceless treasures for all of humanity. 
Thought I am unsure of the other 2 books (Samaveda and Yajurveda).

And as a personal opinion most of the scripts I guess are lost during the time due to war between religions and other natural or man made causes.

Comment: Why are you counting Ayurveda as a Veda?

Comment: @VineetMenon It is believed that Ayurveda is maily derived from Atharva-Veda, So I think it is a type of Veda.

Comment: yeah. You are right. But there's no text named 'Ayurveda' and it is not one among the 4.

Comment: why this vedas are not kept available for all citizens in India as a holy books

Comment: It is true that Vedas were transmitted through memory and hearing, but they were written down during Adi Shankaracharya's time. This version is the "untampered" one and is either with Germany (taken away by Hitler's army), the Britishers or the U.S.A. Most of the "translated" version has lies inserted and many things omitted.