# What are the branches in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas

What are the branches in the Vedas ? There are 1131 branches in Vedas, some of them are extinct.
Then how we can say that the Vedas are in their original form ?

> वेदों की शाखाएं क्या हैं ? वेदों
>   की ११३१ शाखाएं बतलाई जाती हैं,
>   जो बहुत सी लुप्त हो गई हैं, तब यह कैसे
>   माना जाए कि वेद मूल स्वरुप में ही हैं ?

Comment: For last question, see [Where are the original versions of the Vedas?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2628/3500)

Comment: See [here](http://www.encyclopediaofauthentichinduism.org/articles/59_the_vedas_upvedas.htm)