# Does Veda has more than one Samhita regarding to Shakha?

Tags: scripture, vedas, sruti, brahmanas

As I've discussed [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14428/277), we know that ancient Rishi heard Vedic hymns in the state of Tapasya (deep mediation) which are called Shruti/Vedas. Vedas are divided into two parts Samhita - the (mantra) part of Veda seen/heard by Rishi & Brahman-Grantha - interpretation & commentaries on Samhita.

Now talking about [Shakha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakha) (branch of Veda), generally each Shakha have it's own [Brahmana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmana) of which some are lost. Aaranyaka are extracted from Brahmana and Upanishads are extracted from Aaranyaka (except Isha Upanishad). So, each & every Brahman/Aaranyaka/Upanishad belongs to a particular Shakha of a particular Veda.

For example if we talk Rigveda, there are two *popular* shakha - Shakala & Bashkala. Shakala has Aitareya Brahman & Upanishad and Bashkala has Kaushitaki Brahman & Upanishad.

But several times (in books and on web) I found they mention different/various Samhita of a particular Veda. For example (Note that I know that Yajurveda has two forms Shukla & Krishna and hence separate Samhita - which is different topic):

- Taittariya Samhita, Maitrayani Samhita, Charaka-Katha & Kapishthala Samhita of Krishna Yajurveda.
- Kauthuma, Ranayaniya and Jaimini Samhita of Samaveda.

Similar thing I found from the following image of veda-tree at [here](http://indiaculturetree.com/wp-content/uploads/new_ved_tree.jpg):

> [image: veda-tree]

<sup>As I've not [read](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/578/277) any Samhita yet and don't know deeply about Samhita.</sup>

So, I want to know:

- Does Veda has more than one Samhita regarding to Shakha?
- In other words, does Shakha has it's Samhita like Brahmana?
- Or *here* different Samhita just/actually refers to Shakha of Veda?

I think if there are more than one (version) of Samhita of a particular Veda, they might be similar with just minor (chant) difference.

Comment: @Tezz looks like duplicate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Do Veda have more than one Samhita regarding to Shakha?

Yes, each Shakha of Veda has it's own Samhita. There were 21 Shakhas of RigVeda, 1000 Shakhas of SamaVeda, 101 Shakhas of Yajurveda and 9 Shakhas of Atharvaveda as I discuss in my [**answer here.**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15301/are-there-any-variants-in-samhita-of-vedas/15445#15445) Thus total about 1131 Samhitas. We have only about 12 Shakhas alive with 12 Samhitas.

#### In other words, does Shakha has it's Samhita like Brahmana?

Yes, Shakha has it's own Samhita like Brahmana.

Or here different Samhita just/actually refers to Shakha of Veda?
No, here Samhita refers also to actual Samhita.

#### How do Samhitas of same Vedas differ?

I discuss this in my [**answer here.**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15301/are-there-any-variants-in-samhita-of-vedas/15445#15445)

Comment: How can we recover lost vedas?