# How much of the Vedas exist as of present?

Tags: vedas, sruti

I've read somewhere that there are many shakhas of vedas and some of them have been lost, how much of the 4 Vedas have survived to this date?

How many shakhas are surviving, and what are the names of the lost shakhas?

Comment: [Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17531/can-it-be-precisely-known-exactly-how-much-amount-of-vedas-has-been-lost) is a related Q.