# Are there any references for claims that "purush sukta in Rigveda" is an interpolation?

Tags: scripture, vedas, identification-request, manuscripts

Many people **claim** that as per many scholarly studies and references, **"purush sukta in Rigveda  is an interpolation"**

Can somebody provide references to such scholarly studies and references ?

Comment: Indologist studies, they say that because they think that language of that sukta is advanced, Hinduism doesn't accept it though. Ved vyasa arranged suktas in books of 4 Vedas, so there were late suktas which were placed in old books and early suktas in late books of atharva Veda or khillani.

Comment: (1)i wanted **references** to studies about these linguistic claims too
(2) **Are you saying that purush sukta is khila sukta of Rigveda (defn: Khila Suktas of RigVeda are those Suktas which are associated only in Baskala Shakha of RigVeda and not in Sakala Shakha )** ?

Comment: no I'm saying that several suktas which were revealed earlier and had earlier grammar were placed in later books, and khillani books, purush sukta is not from khillani. It might have been a later revelation which was placed in earlier books by ved vyasa himself.

Comment: I thought there was only 1 sakha of rig Veda surviving, also don't all samhitas of all sakhas of one veda have same mantras but having a little difference?

Comment: (1) Sri Suktam of RigVeda is a Khila Sukta.
 (2) Shiva Sankalpa Sukta of RigVeda is also a Khila Sukta . 
(3) But i do not know about Purush sukta status.
also see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17644/is-shiva-sankalpa-suktam-also-a-khila-sukta-of-rigveda?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

So people say the Purusha Suktam is a later interpolation and a casteist verse, but is it? Is there logic behind these claims or is it simply emotions taking over? To summarize the Purusha Suktam states that Brahmins are from the mouth of Purusha, Kshatriya his hands, Vaishya his thighs, and Shudras his feet. Now some people have stated that the mouth is at the top and the feet are at the bottom hence Brahmins are being called supreme and Shudras impure. But, let’s look at each body part from the ground up and look at the deeper analogy. Feet represents support and more than arms show walking and running which is used in manual labor commonly done by the Shudra Varna. Thighs are one of the most meaty parts of the body and symbolize an abundance of resources similar to the job of Vaishyas as merchants. Kshatryias manage, command, fight, and use order. This job requires hands as their instrument. Finally, Brahmins through speech teach the Vedas and recite prayers. We can see a comparison of the different body parts of Ishvara and the occupations of these Varnas. Now yes in some Hindu scriptures, it states that a man’s lower body is impure. This is because the lower areas tend to be dirtier such as the feet touching the ground, hence why it is good to wash your feet before seeing the devata at a temple. But, comparing an ordinary man's anatomy to Purusha is wrong. In Vaishnavism, all parts of Purusha/Vishnu are seen as holy and manifestations of the universe. They especially take note of the feet and surrender to the lotus lord's feet. Hence, the interpretation of this as hierarchy and casteist is shaky. Vedic gods themselves are sometimes poetically compared to cows or bulls. While this verse may be a later addition letting one's own emotions discard certain parts of scripture is dangerous. Also note a good chunk of Vedas are lost to the scholarly world here is the post made by SOMEONE-ELSE for that: `https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17531/can-it-be-precisely-known-exactly-how-much-amount-of-vedas-has-been-lost`

Answer (score 0):

```
  TIME TRAVELS & TRANSCENDENTAL
```

VERSES TRANSCENDING DIRECTLY TO HUMAN MIND - ADVANTAGING THE ESP(Extra Sensory Perception)

PURUSHASUKTA / PURUSHASUKTHAM is a depiction of reality in Time-Travel to explain human-Divine-born about origin of Universe & Human forms on Earth.

It was a "SMRITI & SHRUTHI" perceived by many Divine directly from Divine God.

Entire PURUSHA SUKTHAM was reduced by Divine sages in KaliYuga where Earth was pushed away from Solar control. Sages worked well for humans to pronounce it for idol worship.

```
       MODERN EXPLANATION
```

You know google text to voice
But
Can you imagine PURUSHASUKTAM as PAST-TIME events as imageries, voice, and dream like actual interpretations into minds of those blessed at that time by GOD.

INTERPOLATION??? ==== Not really

Answer (score -8):

In general the tenth mandala of Rig Veda is late.  The Sanskrit has shed many Indo-European elements of Vedic Sanskrit and looks more like Paninean Sanksrit.  While early mandalas are simple hymns to personifications of nature, the tenth mandala has pantheistic speculation which would develop further in Hinduisms later.

Many scholars consider Purusha Sukta an interpolation.

[Sanjay Sonawani](http://independent.academia.edu/SanjaySonawani) quotes [Max Müller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_M%C3%BCller) and [Henry Thomas Colebrooke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Thomas_Colebrooke) in his book [Origins of the Vedic Religion: And Indus-Ghaggar Civilisation](https://books.google.com/books?id=uYBLCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT233&pg=PT233#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Scholars also do agree that there are certain interpolations and
>   corruptions  in Rig Veda. This only will mean that while final
>   codification, divisions  and rearrangements of the hymns and verses of
>   the Rig Veda, some  portion was freshly inserted while some was
>   removed. We start finding  tropical Seasons, animal, plant,
>   agricultural instrument references along  with flora-fauna appearing
>   in Rig Veda only because of this. Of interpolation *purushasukta* is a
>   fine example, which, beyond doubt, has been proved to be the
>   interpolation of far later times.
>
> Max Muller states:
>
> > **There can be little doubt, for instance, that the
> >     90th  hymn of the 10th book (Purusha Sukta) is modern both in its
> >     character  and in its diction**. ( ... ) It mentions the three seasons
> >     in the order of the  Vasanta, spring; Grishma, summer; and Sarad,
> >     autumn; it contains the  only passage in the Rigveda where the four
> >     castes are enumerated. The  evidence of language for the modern date
> >     of this composition is equally  strong. **Grishma**, for instance, **the
> >     name for the hot season, does not  occur in any other hymn of the
> >     Rigveda**; and **Vasanta also does not  belong to the earliest vocabulary
> >     of the Vedic poets**."
>
> Colebrooke states,
>
> > That remarkable hymn (the Purusha Sukta) is in 
> >     language, metre, and style, very different from the rest of the
> >     prayers with  which it is associated. **It has a decidedly more modern
> >     tone**, and **must have been composed after the Sanskrit language had
> >     been refined**, and its  grammar and rhythm perfected."

[T.H.P. Chentharasseri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T._H._P._Chentharasseri) in [*History of the Indigenous Indians*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8HILXitIzoQC&lpg=PA19&pg=PA19#v=onepage&q&f=false) writes:

> The Purushasukta upholding four varnas is a later  composition added
>   to the original Rig Veda. It is evident  from the language of the
>   Sukta as compared with the  language of the rest of the Rig Veda. That
>   it is later  production, is the opinion of all scholars. In support of
>   this argument, Dr. Ambedkar quotes Coleebrook:
>
> > That  the remarkable
> >     hymn (the Purusha Sukta) is in language , metre, and style very
> >     different from the rest of the  prayers with which it is associated.
> >     It has a decidedly  more modern tone and must have been composed after
> >     the Sanskrit language had been refined and its grammar  and rhythm
> >     perfected. The internal evidence it furnishes  serves to demonstrate
> >     the important fact that the  compilation of the Vedas in their present
> >     arrangement  took place, after the Sanskrit tongue had advanced from 
> >     the rustic and irregular dialect in which the multitude of  hymns and
> >     prayers of the Veda was composed to the  polished and sonorous
> >     language in which the  mythological poems, sacred and profane (Puranas
> >     and Kavyas) have been written". The Purusha Sukta which is
> >     considered to be the  nucleus of Rig Veda and the philosophy of
> >     Brahmanism  has not been included in the beginning or in the middle 
> >     portion of Rig Veda but only at the fag end. Similarly the  sum total
> >     of the ideas of Mahabharata is Bhagavat  Gita. It has also been
> >     included only as an appendix to  Mahabharatha. These things show that
> >     these were later  interpolations to fulfill the heinous aims of
> >     Brahmanism.
>
> The Purusha Sukta occurs also in the Atharva Veda  as the
>   supplementary part. If it was the earliest  composition why should it
>   have been placed in such an  inconsequential collection. It means that
>   it was only a  later interpolation in Veda with crooked intentions.
>   The  Purusha Sukta is a forgery by the Brahmins to bolster up  their
>   claim to superiority. **Dr. Ambedkar is of opinion that  the Brahmins
>   had forged the Purusha Sukta at least the  two verses 11 and 12 at
>   some later stage, a long time  after the fourth varna had come into
>   being with a view to  giving the system of Chathurvarnya, the sanction
>   of the Veda**.

G. N. S. Raghavan in [*Discovering the Rigveda*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0kOk299laSwC&pg=PA72#v=twopage) discusses verses 11 and 12:

> #### Purusha Sukta An Interpolation
>
> In order to confer legitimacy on the caste system  with its hereditary
>   and graded inequality, the high  priests of Brahminism who acted as
>   thought moulders  interpolated hymn no. 90, known as the Purusha
>   Sukta,  in the last mandala (Book X) of the Rigveda. This poem 
>   proclaims that the scheme of Chatur Varna (Four Orders  of Society)
>   originated from the immolation of a primal  being in the sacrificial
>   fire. **Verses 11 and 12 of the hymn,  which has a total of 16 verses,
>   are in the form of question-and-answer. The rest of the poem is
>   narrative.** They read as follows:
>
> 11. When they divided Purusha how many  portions did they make?  What do they call his mouth,  What do they call his thighs and feet?
> 12. The Brahmin was his mouth, of both his  arms was the Rajanya made.  His thighs became the Vaisya, from his  feet the Sudra was
>       produced.
>
> If we retain the leading question in verse 11 but  omit the Brahminist
>   answer in verse 12, the poem will  be like many another Rigvedic hymn
>   expressing wonder  at the mystery of the universe and attempting an 
>   imaginative, metaphorical explanation of its origin.
>
> Verse 13 and 14 read:
>
> 13. The moon was born from his mind,  The sun arose from the eye,  Indra and Agni from the mouth,  wind arose from his vital breath.
> 14. The mid-region came from his navel,  The sky came from his head,  The earth from his two feet,  The quarters from the ear —
>
> Thus they set the worlds in order.
>
> This is an unexceptionable hazarding of a poetic guess. **The mischief
>   is in verse 12.** The significance of the anatomical detail is
>   explained in a Brahmana passage of the Yajurveda: "The part of man
>   above the navel is pure; that below is impure" (Sahitya Akademi's 
>   Anthology, Vol. I, p. 147). It sets out the Chatur Varna scheme which
>   forms the bedrock of the Brahminical social system. The four orders
>   or major castes  proliferated over time into hundreds of regional
>   castes  and sub-castes in a complex system of graded inequality.
>
> The doctrine that high and low occupations are  fixed by the caste of
>   one's birth is wholly alien to the  ethos of the Rigveda. It was not
>   to be expected that  Indian Vedic scholars would be troubled by this 
>   inconsistency, steeped as they have been in the belief  that the Veda
>   is of divine origin, the rishis having merely  put into verse what was
>   'revealed' to them.