# How can portions of Vedas get 'lost'?

Tags: vedas, puranas, vedanta, buddhism

This is not a duplicate question. The question isn't how much of it has been lost, but how it was lost.

Vedas had oral tradition and has been preserved by pure memory for thousands of years. How can this be lost? There were always brahmanas, and there are still brahmanas, maintaining guru shishya parampara. There has been brahmanas memorizing skillfully everything for millennia. After all that, how did Vedas ever get 'lost'? From Puranas it  seems that even by the time Puranas were written some of it were lost.

[Can it be precisely known exactly how much amount of Vedas has been lost?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17531/can-it-be-precisely-known-exactly-how-much-amount-of-vedas-has-been-lost)

Did it get gradually lost? Did the mechanism of memorizing every verse and transmitting it orally fail? I have heard some people say that many Islamic invaders came and killed brahmanas and burned down libraries and this is where it got lost, but all brahmanas weren't killed, most brahmanas were alive and also the books burned were mostly Buddhist in Nalanda. Also, as I said it seems Vedas were being lost even before Islamic invaders. So how exactly did such huge volumes get lost? Also in which period did they get lost? Did they mostly get lost early during 1000BC, or did they get lost during medieval era? Did Buddhism conversions contribute to Vedas getting lost?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is appropriate for the History Stack Exchange & can't be answered by the parameters set on this site.

Answer (score -1):

"Brahmanas memorizing skillfully everything - how did Vedas ever get 'lost'?"

```
            TRUTH
```

Though Brahmanas were disciplined, It was very difficult to memorize advanced hymns but all basic vedas were memorized. Rest of difficult Vedic portions were documented on leafbooks.

```
    THE JEALOUS CAPTURERS
```

More and more advanced vedas were recited, Brahmanas were occupied by other religious invaders and those tried to "understand why a simple text : vedas written on leaves with needles were powerful".

Since they were not written in invader's languages and were difficult to understand, invaders burnt them.

Successively from those ancient ages to present era, hymns documented in "non-harming" manner by Brahmanas were under attacks.

The attacks are cited to be through humans due to Satan unable to bear DEMONAIC spirits uncontrolled.

```
 REMAINING PORTION OF VEDAS
```

What is chanted in Temples is just 1/18th of total exemplary Vedas given by God through sages.

For this reason to appreciate all 18 parts of Vedas though we have in KaliYuga just 1 portion of 18 such,
Following festivals are celebrated

18 step foot path darshan to Pamba HariHara

18 days of fasting to bath in South Indian river Cauvery

18 faced Vaishno devi shakthi maata representing protector of sacred vedas

18 chapters of Bhagavad Gita

18 hours of stars in sky orbit
(worshipped in a year as STAR festival on a Friday: (PROOF- 487 representing actual days equivalent to Earth days according to Sanskrit == written form of number 786 (holy number written in "Urdu", easy resembling language to Hindi pronounciation & a middle east language majority invaders learnt to capture North India)).

18 in modern era were the Scheduled Indian(Hindu languages existing both in verbal/scriptic forms BEFORE INVASION from ancient CIVILISATION) recognised by Parliament:
Assamese(Arunachal), Bengali, Carnatic (Kannada,Telugu), Gujarati, Hindi,  Konkani, Malayalam, Manipuri, Marathi, Mythili, Nepali, Odia, Punjabi, Sanskrit, Sindhi, Santhali, Tamil ---
when "Freedom of Speech/Expression" through languages were initiated in recognition to Hindu majority votes to appreciate the "NUMBER 18" representing the 18 Veda portions of Hinduism to World.