# Why is the Kenopanishad also called Talavakara Upanishad?

Tags: kena-upanishad

Also, does any other scripture have multiple names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it belongs to Talavkar (Jaiminiya) [Shakha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15508/277) of Samaveda. Yes, other Upanishads are also known by such names.

- Brihadaranyak Upanishad is also called Vajasneyi Brahmana Upanishad.
- Taittiriya and Aiteriya Upanishads names are based on Shakhas of Krishna Yajurveda and Rigveda respectively

As I have mentioned in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14428/277), Principal Upanishads are part of Aaranyaka or Brahmanas of particular Shakha of Vedas.

As per Mahabhashya of Pantanjali, Samaveda had 1000 (thousand) Shakhas and out of them only 3 are surviving today. 1. Kauthuma, 2. Jaimini and 3. Ranayaniya. Jaimini Rishi is well known for Purva Mimansa Sutra work along with his Guru Vedavyasa for work on Brahma Sutras.

While distributing 4 division of onr Veda to each disciplines, Vedavyasa distributed Samaveda to Jaimini.

As per the [description of Talavkar Aaranyaka](https://vedicheritage.gov.in/aranyakas/talavakararanyaka/),

> According to the Mangalācaraņa of this Āraņyaka, Jaimini was the
> teacher of TalavakāraRși, this text,therefore, can be regarded as written by Talavakāra, a student of Jaimini.

However, no much information is available on [Talavkar Rishi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/55844/277).