# Who was Rishi Talavkara, the founder of Talavkar Shakha of Samaveda?

Tags: rishi, aranyaka

As we know that out of thousand Shakhas of Samaveda, only three are prevailing today - Kauthuma, Jaimini and Ranayani.

Jaimini shakha of Samaveda is also known as Talavkara. No information about Talavkar is available. While answering [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/55840/277), I have found that Talavkar is the name of Rishi who was probably student of Jaimini and this rishi Talavkar has wrote an Aranyaka taught by Rishi Jaimini. This Aranyaka is known as Talavkar Aranyaka and upanishad belonging to it - Kena Upanishad is also many times called "Talavkar Upanishad"

What I found from [preface of the book](https://vedicheritage.gov.in/flipbook/Jaiminiyopanishad_Brahmana/#book/24) is:

> [image: Book Page]

So, it might be interesting to know about Rishi Talavkar. Is any information about him available from Brahmanas or Puranas?

Comment: Good question, but will be difficult to find more than that.