# Where are the original/last known manuscripts of Hindu texts?

Tags: vedas, manuscripts, epics, indology

Where can one find the original manuscripts of the Hindu texts like the Vedas, Upanishads, Mahabharata, Ramayana etc. ? I mean the ones used for the first English translations in the late 1800s by the colonial Indologists like Max Mueller and who gave it to them ?

I see some discussion [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/where-are-the-original-versions-of-the-vedas) but no good answer.

How can one authenticate that whatever versions they had used for the translation are the correct ones and not manipulated ?

Comment: Several.of them you can find on Internet Archive. E.g. [This](https://archive.org/details/Chunilal-Gandhi-Vidyabhavan) is a good collection from Chunilal Gandhi Vidyabhavan, Surat, Gujarat.

Comment: Great, Awesone. Thanks a lot, but why do these manuscripts look like printed ? One of the the timestamp says 1723. Do you know anything more on their history / how they were obtained ?