# Theertha Prasad and Sadari

Tags: belief, puranas

In the Vishnu temples theertha Prasad is offered and thereafter sadari is kept. Some archakas say do not apply the theertha after consuming because sadari is kept on the head which is Nammalwar [sadagopan]. If we apply the remaining theertha it is like abusing sadari as our salaiva also will go on our head with the left out small pinch of theertha. But in big temples like Ranganathaswamy temple of srirangam they will not say this. Any puranic evidence for this.

Comment: +1 Good question. What is difference between Sadri and Sadgopan because I have only experienced Sadgopan no my head nothing else. Generally I don't do that wiping hands on head kind of thing after tirtha prashan, and as far as I have seen no one does that. If you have Urdhwapundra they will do sadgopan two times else they would do it one time.

Comment: @Yogi Sadari, Sadagopam, and Sadagopuram are all different names for the same thing, namely the crown-looking thing that represents the head of Nammalwar and feet of Vishnu as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2755/36  The wiping hands on head thing is extremely common in Sri Vaishnava temples.  In any case, I have never seen a priest put the Sadagopam multiple times on someone useless they've performed Sharanagati.

Comment: If the only reason why you shouldn't put the Thirtham on the head is that it's disrespectful when the Sadagopam is placed, then presumably it wouldn't be mentioned in Puranas or other scriptures, since the practice of Sadagopam was created by Sri Vaishnavas to honor Nammalwar.  So at most we would find discussion of this in the works of Sri Vaishnava Acharyas:

Comment: @both--thanks for your views. Wiping the water to my knowledge is that it eradicates the sin from head to toe. A devotee should be careful before  wiping on head. He should not suck the tirtha Prasad . If he do so then he may wipe in his angavastram so that sadagopam  is given due respect.