# Why is Sadari placed on the palms of Vishwa Brahmins?

Tags: temple, practice

[Sadari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFQBM.jpg) in temple is placed on the head for the people and my question is why the sadari is placed only on the palms for Vishwa brahmins?

So please give me a clarification about both the differences.

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2675/what-is-the-significance-of-satagopuram

Comment: Hello Welcome to [hinduism.se]. The title is not the entire question. The question should be in body and not the title. Title is just an intro. I have edited it for you. When you post a new question, please take of this.  Take a [tour] and [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33/5212). Also, can you say where have you observed this practice? I know putting Sadari at our shoulders and not palms.