# Most important lesson

Tags: vishnu, krishna, ramayana

Even though Hinduism teaches us about a lot of aspects of life I was curious to know which ones of them are the most influential in our daily life ?

Comment: What influences you most depends on your personality and what moves you most. In general, the tenets that are universally applicable and will have a positive impact on the individual and society are : satyam vada, dharmam chara, maatru devo bhava,pitru devo bhava and acharya devo bhava"

Comment: IMHO the practice of Ahimsa is the greatest and best lesson for general public. Ahimsa - non-violence in thought, word and deed, if practiced sincerely, will lead to improved humanity and foster the feeling of Ekatma Bhava. All the best

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the Hindu scriptures which every Hindu should abide by?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/54/what-are-the-hindu-scriptures-which-every-hindu-should-abide-by)

Comment: Sorry to close your question but it is too broad. I would like to narrow down the scope of your question here so please edit it accordingly and flag your question for reopen.

Comment: How come it be broad !!! I just wanted to know which ones is the most influential or let's having the most strongest charge amongst all the lessons in Hinduism so @mr.alien where do I step onto broadness ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ofcourse, Bhagavad Gita is the most important lesson or message to the mankind. This has been even told by the current PM of India while gifting Gita to the Japanese prime minister.

Gita has been [revealed more than once](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/4/1). What Krishna told to Arjuna was the latest version which got famous through current Hinduism.

To be specific within Gita, the most important message *should be*:

> > ***Renunciation of the fruits of actions.***

This particular message has been described multiple times in Gita itself.
The most famous of them are:
[Chapter 2.47](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/2/47)

> You have a right to perform your prescribed duty, but you are **not
>   entitled to the fruits of action**. Never consider yourself the cause of
>   the results of your activities, and never be attached to not doing
>   your duty.

[Chapter 12.12](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/12/12)

> If you cannot take to this practice, then engage yourself in the
>   cultivation of knowledge. Better than knowledge, however, is
>   meditation, and better than meditation is **renunciation of the fruits
>   of action**, for by such renunciation one can attain peace of mind.

Answer (score 1):

The answers are highly subjective. In my case, I would say that `What you sow is what you reap` together with life after death is the most important lesson. All other aspects can be considered as a ramification of this.